# Is there a delete queue similar to a close queue?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently looked at the Review tab and noticed that there is not a Delete Queue, for answers that have one or more delete votes but have not yet been deleted.

Does this queue exist under a different name, in a different location or is it non-existent?

If it is one of the first two, where can it be found?
If it is the last one, why is there no queue?

Comment: We have had a long time request for creating an "actual" delete queue. [The current one](http://stackoverflow.com/tools) is pretty suboptimal to use.

Answer (score 10):

There is, but you can find it in the [tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) tab, not the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) tab (10K only).

Comment: Could you be more specific? I see a list of recent deletes, not a queue of answers to be voted on.

Comment: @merlin2011: See http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=today.

Comment: I think the VLQRQ is what OP is looking for...

Comment: @Vogel612: No, there is a queue for delete votes too, but only for privileged users.

Comment: @PatrickHofman If I understand the /tools correctly, that is just a list of posts with (un)delete-votes on them / posts that were deleted recently, and not a "review queue" similar to the close queue

Comment: @Vogel612: Well, a list or a queue is actually the same, right?

Comment: @PatrickHofman well aside from the problem that a review *queue* only presents one item at a time and only a fixed set of possible actions (recommend deletion/delete, edit, looks ok, skip)  ;)

Comment: @Vogel612: I don't see the issue with it. It works as fast as the review queue in my opinion.

Comment: Yes I did find it but no I don't think it works as fast as the close queue.

Answer (score 3):

There is no delete *queue* that looks like the regular queues. But there is a place where you can find something similar. It's more of a list of recent/most delete/undelete votes.

1. Click the review button.
2. Click [tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) and it will look something like this:

[image]

3. Click "Delete" (marked with red)
4. You're done. You can adjust the time, but there it is. It looks like this:

[image]