# HIQ "very low quality" link

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts, triage, help-improvement

It looks like a "question is very low quality" link was added to the HIQ (Help and Improvement Queue) recently.

When should I click on this link? Should I click it anytime I think the question deserves to be closed? Or only if I think the question should be deleted?

I'm kinda confused since it does a "very low quality" flag, when I thought we were phasing that out of existence.

[image]

Comment: VLQ flags have been disallowed  in some situations, but they are here to stay, and were meant to fill this part of the [question review cycle](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278380/3717023).

Comment: ["the main issue with design of new queue is an assumption that Triage feed is mostly flawless ..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue#comment163850_287466)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Remember that flowchart I posted when [announcing the Triage queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage)?

[image]

Geoff just drew in that last line. If you come across something in the Help and Improvement queue that's just... *Painfully* bad... You now have an escape hatch, a way to send it back into Triage for a second look.

### The VLQ flag is dead - long live VLQ!

The Very Low Quality flag was *[always](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/165773)* intended to mean "this is so awful it should be deleted"... But unfortunately, that's been a bit fuzzy for quite some time now, as the only way for folks who aren't moderators to *handle* these flags is to... close. And once you equate "awful" with "close", folks start to turn that around, thinking "if it can be closed, it must be Very Low Quality!"

But that's nonsense. Plenty of questions should be closed but aren't abysmal crap. We don't need a *flag* to pile on top of (Recommend) Close votes - if you think a question is poorly-written *and* worth closing, then just downvote it before you close-vote it. We don't really need this flag at all...

...Except, it's just so damn useful.

Lots of folks struggle to understand our close reasons... But they know "ugh" when they see it. Giving them an easily-identifiable way to communicate this benefits everyone, *as long as that signal is interpreted properly*.

Enter Triage: a system designed from the start for differentiating between "good enough", "has fixable problems" and, uh, "ewwww". Of the three options available, two dispute the flag and the last... Well, passes it on to someone else for a closer look and, in all likelihood, deletion.

*All* questions flagged Very Low Quality now immediately enter Triage; if you check the Low Quality review queue on Stack Overflow, you'll see there are no questions there anymore. Flags that can't be handled by Triage are still passed on to moderators, but review gets a running start at them - and an opportunity to do some heavy-duty filtering, with the aim of reducing the number of misguided flags that moderators have to decline.

Oh, and while these questions are being triaged, they're *not* shown on the home page. Take *that*, [wall of crap.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258699/the-stack-overflow-homepage-is-over-emphasizing-bad-questions-and-a-proposed-so)

These changes just rolled out this evening; we'll be keeping a sharp eye on it for the next few days, and likely making a few tweaks, but hopefully this'll provide the missing piece of the quality-control puzzle we started putting together months back.

Comment: If this is a review action, why isn't it a Big Blue Button like all the other ones?

Comment: is there a plan to extend this feature [to other sites](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/7130?lq=1 "Take that wall of crap")?

Comment: Given the flag decline in [this MSO question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288399/289086), should additional guidance on the handling of VLQ flags that meet this intended criteria be given? If not, I fear that getting flag declines from this action could turn people off from using the queue even more.  In essence the mods saying "nope, you've got to deal with this crap yourself"

Comment: There is, @Alexis - it's called "Skip". The flagging part isn't a review action, it's just something you can do if you see the need.

Comment: I don't know why that flag was declined, @MichaelT. Other than that we've been shoving entirely too many of these at the mod team and they're getting cynical about it. Which... This *should* help.

Comment: This is all pretty much tailored to the needs of Stack Overflow, @gnat. Not that this precludes using it elsewhere - but that's a discussion we'll need to have separately.

Comment: I see, thanks. Few months ago, I asked related "support" question at Progs meta: [Is there a plan to test Triage review at Programmers?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7053/31260) If you don't plan addressing it anytime soon, I will consider "converting" it into such a discussion. If you prefer to have network wide discussion (as opposed to per site), I can launch it at MSE, just let me know

Comment: @Shog9 the understanding that I have of what the mods understand to be an actionable VLQ flag is gibberish.   If you can read it, it isn't VLQ.  It seems to be based off of http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167641/ "You should not use it to describe the following, but should be using close votes, down votes and / or edits instead * Questions that can be understood, but don't provide enough detail * Questions that are clearly off topic".  If those two  items *should* be flagged as VLQ, then some modifications to the instructions given to mods on how to handle those cases is likely in order.

Comment: @MichaelT But if I read the post correctly, now VLQ flags on questions are no longer for mods at all -> it's 100% Triage. (Shog9: this may be worth explaining, since mod criteria were historically different from reviewers criteria)

Comment: @Woodface I can still VLQ flag answers which aren't triage.  And the VLQ still feeds the VLP queue.

Comment: @MichaelT It seems we're getting off-track here... VLQQ and VLQA flags now go to separate queues and mean different things; the mods' criteria for VLQA are separate from anything involving triage.

Comment: @Woodface the wording on the two flags are identical other than question / answer: "This question / answer has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed."  Having them mean two different things with the same wording could be part of this confusion. And that said, the understanding I have of mod understanding of VLQ* is that it has to be gibberish for them to act on it. They decline blatantly off topic flags with a VLQ which is what Shog appears to pointing out. There is also the question of *old* questions.

Comment: there you go: [Triage and Help & Improvement review queues at sites other than Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251737/165773) -- just posted that ["separate discussion"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288385/hiq-very-low-quality-link/288387?noredirect=1#comment167554_288387) at MSE (while drafting it I figured that it seems to make better sense network wide than at Programmers meta)

Comment: Shouldn't a VLQ-flag cast from triage imply an "unsalvagable"-review from the caster for the Triage-queue?

Comment: @Woodface: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288440/under-the-new-triage-system-when-and-how-should-moderators-act-on-very-low-qua/288450#288450

Comment: It does, @Deduplicator. If that isn't the result, the flag will be marked "disputed".

Comment: What happens if a question continually circles between Triage and HIQ? Is there any logic like "If the question gets HIQ'd more than x times we just throw it out?"

Comment: There's a time-limit, @David - eventually, it doesn't get any more chances.

Comment: It does not seem like this link consistently raises a flag (from this one users perspective), nor removes item from queue.

Comment: "take _that_, wall of cr@p" -- from what I recently learned there may be a typo here, should it read "[_take_ that wall of cr@p"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374881/839601)?