# Double Review in Triage

Tags: bug, review-queues, triage

I reviewed the same question in Triage twice.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7409340

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7409299

It is the same Question: 29162117

Comment: Because 3 users clicked on "should be improved", it sent the question to the Help and Improvement Queue. Then someone probably flagged that question as very low quality from the HIQ. So it sent it back into the Triage queue, as [explained here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288387/3041194). I don't think the same user's should be able to review it twice in Triage.

Comment: @Roombatron5000 So it went Triage->HIQ->Triage->HIQ->... I wonder where the question is now.

Comment: I have had the same with http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7827638 and http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7827724, less then 2 minutes apart. the question is now gone, although it could have been salvaged easily IIRC.

Comment: Same: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9558691 and http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9558879. I think CRABOLO's explanation is still valid, but in any case I agree with him: the same user shouldn't be able to review it twice.