# Very low quality flag not showing up in triage queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

When I go through the triage queue, I have noticed that when I click on unsalvageable, it brings up a menu that is almost - but not quite - identical to that which comes up when I flag a question. However the very low quality flag is missing. Similarly, this flag is absent when I try to flag a quesiton from the first post queue.

Why was this flag excluded when in the queue?

Comment: Because if a question is flagged "Very Low Quality", that question is sent to Triage. It'd be pretty pointless to flag a question in that queue as "Very Low Quality" if you come across it there. You'd just be piling on flags, not getting anything done about the question.

Comment: See [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288387/2607247) by Shog for a better explanation.

Comment: @Kendra Thanks. That answered my question nicely.