# Help and Improvement queue skip item leading to removal of item

Tags: feature-request, help-improvement

The Help and Improvement queue has been growing lately. This includes more reviews that I really have no clue on how to improve with editing, and for at least a few of those I think they should not have been in the queue in the first place.

I know how to press *Skip*, so that is not the problem. But that means the question shows up on someone else's plate to review, and she might *Skip* as well if there is really nothing to improve, etc.

Does this mean such a review item stays in the queue forever, or until someone makes a token edit that doesn't improve anything (I must admit I did this once or twice until I realized I might just really not get what could be improved)?

Is there some mechanism in place to remove an item from the queue if skipped a specific number of times? Or something else that prevents items to live in the queue forever? If so, what is it? If not, could that be implemented?

Comment: Anything that shouldn't have been put in the queue in the first place should either get a trivial edit to polish it up (if it was actually fine, which is probably common) or get [VLQ'ed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288385/hiq-very-low-quality-link) back to Triage.

Comment: Good question, wondered this as well. @NathanTuggy yea, we could do trivial edits, but that is against the editing policies, so don't know if that's the best thing to do.

Comment: @Roombatron5000: If it legitimately doesn't need any further help, what else should you do?

Comment: @NathanTuggy "should either get a trivial edit to polish it up (if it was actually fine" Instead of making cosmetic edits for the sake of clearing the H&I queue, wouldn't it be more productive to prevent "actually fine" posts from ever getting there?

Comment: @IanKemp: You mean making the Triage queue perfectly accurate? Yeah, that'd sure be nice. Go for it!

Comment: @NathanTuggy I've already brought up my issues with the Triage queue elsewhere. What I was more getting at is that, perhaps there should be some sort of penalty (similar to failing a review) if someone sends a large number of posts to H&I, but that that queue's reviewers can't see how to improve said posts.

Comment: @IanKemp: Hmm. There are two ways I can see to track that; the first is to add yet another link like the VLQ flag in HI to say that this should be kicked out; both of these could then be instrumented to check for reviewers that frequently contribute to bad decisions. The other is to, ironically and contrary to my earlier suggestion, hit the VLQ flag, which does, after all, already signal a disagreement with the earlier Triage decision, and also sends it back... ready to be marked Looks OK this time around, one hopes.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I am not sure why you think that the post that don't need editing are VLQ. All of the ones I was considering are normal quality, Or are you not talking about the quality of the original post, but the status as review item?

Comment: @Anthon: The "VLQ" link primarily kicks (or [is supposed to kick](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289999/flagging-vlq-from-hi-doesnt-use-up-flags-per-day)) reviews from H&I back to Triage, and there's nothing that says Triage can't take a "VLQ"-flagged question and call it Looks OK. It's hackish, but it should work.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I don't see why you would want to use such a confusing terminology as VLQ and not some word or acronym that describes the action and or the post non-ambiguously.

Comment: @Anthon: It's not my terminology. The link in HIQ that does this is labeled "question is very low quality". That's what it says. (The fact that that's not exactly what we're using it for is the hackish part, of course.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy It doesn't matter much where it comes from. You are using it in a context that makes it unclear to me what you are referring to, right from the first comment you made. And if I need to read through multiple comments to get a hope of understanding what you mean *you* are not getting the message a cross that you want to give by using that term. That is my warning, but maybe I am to dumb and others do understand your interpretation. (And I know what the VLQ links is, I have used it often enough).

Comment: @Anthon: I figured you did, but I also figured the potholed link in my first comment would clarify that yes, I did mean *that* VLQ.