# Should closeable questions in Help&Improvement be edited-out then closed or flagged as VLQ?

Tags: discussion, support, help-improvement

I tried going through the Help and Improvement queue today, since it's the one I'm the least familiar with so far, and I was given [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29557844/1). [I tried my best](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557844/how-to-load-data-by-column-and-line-from-a-text-file-into-mysql) at editing the question, understanding the original problem, and reformulating it.

But now that I've already sent my edit, I realize that the question is probably way too broad to get a good answer, and should probably be closed. I'm not sure how to best handle the situation and what to do in the future. If I had realized the problem sooner, should I have:

- Canceled my edit, skipped, and added a third vote to get it closed quickly?
- Canceled my edit, [flagged as VLQ and sent it back to Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288385/hiq-very-low-quality-link), hoping Triage would make a different decision this time?
- Canceled my edit, flagged as VLQ *and* voted to close?
- Kept my edit to get it out of the queue, and waited to see how the system would handle it?

From what I've read on Meta so far, it seems that the "question is very low quality" link is supposed to handle this.  But on the other hand I'm [reading that it's okay to send even trivial edits to get that post out of the queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289963/help-and-improvement-queue-skip-item-leading-to-removal-of-item).

If a question already went to Triage and I send it back there without any change, isn't it wasting valuable reviewer time? Isn't it going to just keep moving back and forth stuck between two queues until it gets enough close votes, or somehow gets a great answer?

Comment: There are *some* good reviewers in Triage, and some not so. So the idea of sending it back is to try to get it past more of the good this time around.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I'm not too comfortable with that idea, though. It doesn't seem very clean and efficient to throw the post back in Triage until they happen to agree with me. Is that really the best solution? I think that in the case of this particular post, without the edit many people will see the bad English and click "Should Be Improved" without trying to first evaluate whether the underlying question may be unsalvageable. That and people thinking "Should Be Improved" means "Not Literally Impossible To Improve".

Comment: The main solution is to improve Triage guidance/audits until it's more accurate, but until then, even with a 25% false positive rate for SBI, repeated Triagings should usually do the job.

Comment: In any case, there's certainly no justification for editing to get it out if it really should be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making trivial edits in HIQ shouldn't really be done ever. But if you want, only do them when there is really nothing to improve on the question, because the question is already very good question! So don't do it on questions that should be closed.

What I have done before and what you could do, is flag these questions that should be closed in HIQ as "very low quality".. and then when you got time go to your flag history page, and open those questions and then do a close vote on them as well.

So I'd do both, VLQ flag, and vote to close them.

Comment: You know that you can use the "link" link (?) in the HIQ to get to the question, also, clicking the title should open the question too.