# Flagging VLQ from H&I doesn't work for me

Tags: bug, flags, help-improvement

I wasn't expecting to run out of flags anytime soon, but to go through half a dozen mis-triaged questions in H&I and not use up any flags is a bit disconcerting. Pretty sure the daily limits should apply here, *either* by making "question is very low quality" a review action, *or* by deducting each one from daily flags, or even both.

Worse yet, after checking one or two by going back in history and refreshing, the reviews appear to still be in the queue.

Comment: Umm I'm a little confused. I don't see any recent activity from you in the Help & Improvement queue, or any recent VLQ flags in your flag history.

Comment: @animuson: Well, no, you wouldn't. The VLQ links don't, apparently, register; and while I have in the past gone in and actually edited, right now I don't have the emotional energy to do that so I'm skipping anything that's a valid entry.

Comment: @animuson: That said, maybe there's actually something keeping the flags from being generated at all?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure *what* you're actually doing. When you click Skip, absolutely nothing happens with the post. The review gets re-assigned to someone else.

Comment: @animuson: Right, I'm skipping anything that belongs in the queue and flagging anything that needs to be re-triaged. Of which there is a surprising amount.

Comment: @animuson: Nope, I'm using the "question is very low quality" link from the queue.

Comment: Ah, I see. You're using the "question is very low quality" link on the right? I'm not sure what exactly the button does. It doesn't seem to raise an *actual* VLQ flag though.

Comment: @animuson: I see. Hrm. That's certainly very confusing, then.

Comment: Weird, when I just tried it on a post it did create a very low quality flag on the post... It immediately ended the Help & Improvement review and started a Triage review.

Comment: @animuson: The system just doesn't like me?

Comment: Just tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556607/need-to-hide-vertical-overflow-from-the-top directly from the [queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/7639029), in case knowing which question it was makes it easier to check.

Comment: I've noticed this happens to me as well , just sometimes.. I think it maybe has to do with if the question already was in HIQ, someone else or you already did low quality on it, sending it back to triage, and then getting should be improved to HIQ again... so it's maybe not eligible to go back to triage again? Just speculation.

Comment: @Roombatron5000: If so, that's a bad sign, since I've tried almost a dozen and apparently none of them has gone through.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all it does is invalidate the review item in H&I and move it straight into LQRQ.

Comment: @bjb568: animuson's experience was that it generated a flag as expected (see above); mine was that the H&I review *was not even invalidated* on at least one such question. Because, as previously noted, the system apparently hates me! ;)

Comment: Oh, well the system is confusing.

Comment: @bjb Questions don't go to LQRQ anymore.

Comment: The experience I've had with "flagging" from H&I is that the flag does get created, but every one was eventually disputed.  I was only trying during the "no qs in vlq" transition, so maybe that had something to do with it.  Anyway, I agree that it's not obvious that the button is working or getting results.

Comment: So, if I understand... You flag VLQ in HIQ using QiVLQ link, but this VLQ (which is not a QS) is still in HIQ instead of LQPQ. Ya... pretty confusing...

Comment: @zessx: I don't know what QS stands for, but otherwise I guess so.