# How to remove off-topic questions from H&I queue?

Tags: support, review-queues, help-improvement

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/8185500

Question above is blatantly, obviously off-topic, yet somehow ended up in H&I queue.

When coming across such questions, what is the correct action to take? I would usually "skip" but that just means it will present to other people, doesn't it?

---

<sub>Update</sub>

On further investigation (read: particularly slow day at office), clicking on the "question is very low quality" link prompts about raising a flag, but does not consistently do so judging from my flagging summary. It also doesn't seem to remove the item from the H&I review queue, as it is advertised to do.

However, clicking out of the review queue and raising a close flag on the question (off topic, too broad, etc.) *does* appear to consistently remove it from the H&I queue. Is this behavior considered harmful?

Comment: Are you sure you want to send it back to the Triage queue?  Enough energy has been wasted on this garbage.  Yell at the screen, downvote the question, only way to feel better about it.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure it should go back to triage in cases where I'm 100% confident it's crap (I would like the power to just put the crap on hold) but I think the system should be made to work, if possible. else what's the point? And... I've run out of downvotes today. :(

Comment: @HansPassant And, rereading my question, I didn't say I wanted to send things back to triage. Just remove them from H&I. There is a difference. :)

Comment: I assumed you read Martijn's post, he explained that the only way to remove it is to send it back to Triage.  This catch-22 is quite intentional btw, the kind of excess that's induced when your free time has no value.  Only thing you can do about *that* is not waste it.

Answer (score 4):

Use the dedicated link to tell the system the post doesn't belong in the H&I queue:

<kbd>[image: circled *question is very low quality* link]</kbd>

The [*question is very low quality* link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288385/hiq-very-low-quality-link) puts the question back into the Triage queue, where reviewers get another shot at closing it:

> If you come across something in the Help and Improvement queue that's just... *Painfully* bad... You now have an escape hatch, a way to send it back into Triage for a second look.

Comment: `where reviewers get another shot at closing it, ` *and you get another disputed flag.* :) The people viewing things in triage a second time don't seem any more reliable than the people viewing it the first time. I've tried this link several times before and it never seems to have much impact.

Comment: but thank you for your response on the "official" action to take. :)

Comment: @TZHX: the system is still in development; if posts go several runs through Triage and H&I before being closed, that's signal there are still things to improve.

Comment: How many people need to click "question is very low quality" for it to be removed from H&I?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: It also doesn't seem to consistently raise a flag, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/8206745 I clicked that link, but see no flag in my flag summary for it and item is still reviewable -- going outside of the review and flagging as "unclear what you're asking" seems to actually remove it / mark it not reviewable.

Comment: @TZHX: I had an awful time a while ago hitting that link maybe a dozen times on different reviews with not a single one of them actually doing thing one to take those posts out of the queue. See [Flagging VLQ from H&I doesn't work for me](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289999) for details.