# 'Help and Improvement' needs help

Tags: feature-request, help-improvement

It looks to me as if the help and improvement queue contains the debris resulting from some confused individuals processing the Triage queue. All the question I see in there need closure. *Maybe* a few could be cleaned up by their OPs to be legitimate -- *none* could be cleaned up by anyone else, as they all seem to be missing critical bits.

Could we have close buttons so that we can pick up after the triage failure?

Comment: Isn't that what the [HIQ "very low quality" link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288385/hiq-very-low-quality-link) is for?

Comment: @Nathan - I'd say no. When I want to begin the close process for a question in the queue, I cannot. All I can do is move the problem around.

Comment: @Nathan I was using the VLQ option for a while but eventually (through a number of declined flags) learnt that flagging as VLQ should be considered a "nuclear option." As OP has suggested, what the HIQ needs is a direct link to "Vote to Close" pop-up.