# How to Close a question in the Help and Improvement queue?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, help-improvement

This is similar to ['Help and Improvement' needs help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289998/608639) and [HIQ “very low quality” link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288385/608639).

Most of the questions I have seen in Help and Improvement are misclassified and many should be closed. There is a link *"very low quality"*, but it does not allow me to begin the Close process.

I *think* the link moves the question to another queue. *If* the question is moved to another queue, then how do I follow it into the other queue so I can begin the Close process?

Or, more generally, how do I begin the close process and actually cast the close vote with a reason for a question in the Help and Improvement queue?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339462/we-finally-need-more-appropriate-review-actions-in-help-and-improvement)

Answer (score 5):

Many of the questions entering the HI queue should be closed because many of the questions entering Triage should be closed.

...Fact is, we can't close them all. There are too many such questions and too few people voting to close. Most of them won't get answered anyway, and will eventually just be deleted automatically by the system, so voting to close them is... Sort of a waste of time. [It may even end up convincing folks who shouldn't be here to stick around longer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216683/what-happens-to-new-users).

Hence "triage" - put the effort where it'll do the most good. If it's *egregiously* bad, liable to cause harm to others, it needs to be closed and/or deleted ASAP - otherwise, sweep it into a corner and let the roomba take care of it.

So to answer your question... If you can't fix a post in HIq, just skip. UNLESS it strikes you as being so terrible in some way that it transcends just being *bad* and demands immediate attention - in which case, use that Very Low Quality link. That link *may or may not* put the question back into Triage - don't worry about that.

Alternately, you can break out of review and just cast a close vote at any time for any reason you want:

[image: the "link" link in the sidebar takes you to the post]

If your ultimate goal is to close a specific question, there's no need to mess around with review at all; just go directly to the question and vote to close it.

Comment: Same question every few weeks...Could we finaly redirect this to the devs? With this amount of questions, there must be an error in the system.