# Triage "Requires Editing" Notification to New Reviewers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, triage, help-improvement

I have noticed quite a bit of very *low-quality* questions in the **[Help and Improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper)** review queue, [such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/18900707) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/18942788).

Most of the blame is that triage fails to properly explain to new reviewers on the use of the **Requires Editing** selection.

To a new reviewer, Requires Editing seems like a viable option to most of the questions asked; after all, if the OP would edit the question to make it on-topic, then that's better then saying the question is *unsalvageable*, right?

Wrong.

Unknown to most new reviewers - really not to any fault of their own - is the very vaguely tied-in support information on how to pass judgment on low-quality questions.

## My Proposal

For the first x amount of times (let's say 20) that a new reviewer clicks *Requires Editing,* a notification will appear and prompt the reviewer with something along the lines of:

> **Notice:** You are saying that this question is on topic and in an answerable state. This question has minor issues that **you can see yourself being able to correct by editing**. If you believe that you wouldn't be able to edit the question yourself, then you may need to select **Unsalvageable** instead.
>
> <kbd>Continue with Requires Editing</kbd> <kbd>Go Back</kbd> <kbd>Skip</kbd>

I do enjoy the idea of community moderating, and while the community should be able to value its own opinion on what is considered on-topic or not - I believe this should still have a general consensus as to what the baseline expectations are and make that clear in the review queues.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319128/triage-review-queue-inconsistent-guidelines-for-requires-editing?rq=1

Comment: Part of the problem is that the guidance in the review queue itself says that if "edits **by the author** or by others" can fix the post, use "Requires Editing". See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321895/change-triage-guidelines-for-requires-editing

Comment: @gparyani Yes, the meaning I think is *"Requires Editing for questions where edits by **any user** could result in a question that is clear and answerable"*, specifically mentioning the author is the problem

Comment: I think 20 is too much; maybe 5 is enough.

Comment: @gparyani the number can even be dynamic. Saying a minimum of 5, but if your responses tend to lean more towards the **Requires Editing** while others lean more towards **Unsalvageable** then you may be lucky enough to see the prompt more than others.

Comment: 99 views and already 25 up-votes and no down-votes. I think you struck a nerve...

Comment: While I support doing this, the real first step is to change the text that gives guidance for "Requires Editing". Currently, reviewers are doing exactly what the guidance is telling them to do. Expecting them to do differently isn't realistic. The *real problem* is that SE hasn't bothered to change that text in the **2 years** since the [change was requested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321895/3773011). It's unconscionable that a change which would take such a low level of effort, but would at least start guiding people in the right direction, hasn't happened in the last 2 years.

Comment: I was one of those clicking "Requires editing" way too often. Only after almost 20 reviews did it become obvious to me that I was doing it wrong. And I only discovered that because I was randomly browsing Meta, not because the queue taught me how to do it. So we definitely need some better guidance for new reviewers.

Comment: Suggestion: "you can see yourself being able to correct by editing" should be "you can see yourself being able to correct by editing **without involving OP**". I know the sentence already says that enough; but being explicit/verbose is better.

Comment: There's a [full guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674) linked from the top of every Triage review that is a heck of a lot more nuanced than the single-sentence descriptions shown to new reviewers, @Makyen.

Comment: @Shog9, Thanks for mentioning that, I was not remembering that the link was there. However, it really doesn't change how I feel about the short description being directly contrary to what's actually desired, and the fact that something so simple hasn't been changed. It's just text. Sure, it may need to be localized/translated for other sites, but that can just be put into a queue for accomplishing localization (or however, it's done at SE).

Comment: @Shog, If we're getting into the Triage interface, it's unclear to me why there's an "Unsalvageable" button. What's actually being asked of users there is to either flag, or vote-to-close (if > 3k rep). Calling it "Unsalvageable" just creates an additional, confusing semantic which is different than elsewhere on the site. IMO, a much better UX would be to just call it what it is: "Flag", "Flag or Close", or even better: two buttons "Flag" and "Close". This would keep, and reinforce, the semantics which are already used throughout the site, which is what users are already familiar with.

Comment: You're assuming more familiarity than is warranted, @makyen. Most folks don't use either of those functions often (or at all); one of the lessons we learned when rolling out the close review queue was that an awful lot of people would click "close" regularly just to remind themselves of what options were there. Similarly, we redesigned the flag dialog for Triage to summarize the options; the distinction between various flags or close reasons isn't as obvious to many people as it is to folks whi have been using them for years.

Comment: @Shog9 I can understand that. The flag dialog appears to be the same between Triage/questions. I assume it was redesigned and used for both (looks good). Due to character limitations, I left out the benefit of using the same semantics that using such results in people *becoming* more familiar with them, rather than training them on some unique semantic which is only used in that circumstance. I would assume that it's better to have people overall more familiar with the site. Using the same semantics, to mean effectively identical things, is helpful in that regard.

Comment: As a new reviewer, I just need to say I totally missed all the signs and made some base assumptions about what the "needs editing" button was for. I sometimes still hit it by accident, followed by a loud expletive. It seems so native to say to the OP "this needs editing"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the pop-up would just be annoying. Worse, there's a very real chance it would train reviewers to click through pop-ups without reading them - a dangerous approach given that the other pop-ups in review are attached to things like deletion.

But, I like the approach you took with wording. It's long, but it side-steps the problems inherent in asking reviewers to guess at what others are able to fix by focusing on what *the reviewer themselves* believes is fixable. So, as of today, the guidance now reads:

[image: Requires Editing for questions that you can make clear and answerable by editing]

...and also includes a second link to [this meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674) as the last line in the expanded instructions (same answer linked to in "help separating questions" in the short explanation at the top).

Answer (score 16):

So...

We had this idea, back on about three years ago, that the Help & Improvement queue would be sort of a *mentoring* system for new users. Not, "hey, here's where you fix code formatting" but rather "hey, here's where you add clarity and apply some *socratic method* to get folks to think about the questions they're writing"...

...That may have been a bit ambitious.

As a result, most of the stuff in the H&I queue is crap because most of the stuff going into Triage is crap. It's not the *worst of the worst*, but it's certainly not gonna be stuff that you'd seek out ordinarily. Also, we don't actually *tell* anyone that their question has been identified as borderline and in need of serious help - so they're not exactly primed to cooperate with the process either. We *intended* to do that, but kinda ran out of resources before we could agree on a method of doing so; there's probably a nice way of telling someone "hey, your question is in purgatory", but it's beyond my skill.

Aaaanyway, I like your idea. Your proposed wording is too verbose, but admonishing the reviewer to *use their own judgement* is a good approach: one thing I've repeatedly observed is that folks tend to overestimate what askers are able to accomplish on their own and *underestimate* what 3rd-party editors can do - often severely. Asking the reviewer to apply their own experience and mark the question for editing if they could imagine *themselves* fixing it perhaps would side-step this problem.

Comment: My experience: Ten H&I ~ Five CV.

Comment: I recall that when H&I was new, a review there was hard work. It had to satisfy several criteria. Nowadays, even the tiniest edit counts as a review there. I suppose those hard criteria were softened for a reason. But if we want it to be a mentoring system, the bar should be a little higher.

Comment: I think there's been a prior proposal to just rename the button from "requires editing" to (something along the lines of) "I could edit this." They wouldn't need to edit it, but it would be clear that it wasn't *authorial edits* but rather *community edits* could salvage it.

Comment: -1 for supporting this suggestion without even acknowledging [Makyen's objection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363221/triage-requires-editing-notification-to-new-reviewers?cb=1#comment556719_363221). Users who mark close-worthy posts as "Requires Editing" do so because the instructions they are explicitly given in the review queue require them to. The solution to users following bad instructions is not to then immediately scold them for not magically knowing that they should've disobeyed you; it's to stop telling them to do the wrong thing in the first place.

Comment: @MarkAmery In Shog's defense, he answered this @ `2018-02-10 23:40:32Z`, whereas Makyen's objection didn't come in until `2018-02-11 03:34:24Z` (approx 4 hours later)

Comment: @TheNotSoGuru Oops. Yeah, complaining that Shog didn't answer a comment that didn't yet exist is, uh, perhaps asking a bit much. The underlying issue still stands, though (and has been complained about on Meta over and over for the last two years).

Comment: @MarkAmery Regardless of when the comment came in, you and Makyen have a valid point and they probably just need to overhaul the entire guidance of the review queue altogether... It's all pretty vague (if not contradictory to what is _actually_ expected) imho.

Comment: To be clear, I think K.Dᴀᴠɪs's strategy could work just as well as a replacement for the current guidance, @Mark. The issue I've had with previous suggestions for altering that guidance is that they badly want to ask reviewers to predict whether or not the question is complete in its current form - that is, they must be able to say with confidence that the question can be corrected by a 3rd-party; in keeping with the triage metaphor, this is akin to demanding that a hospital admit patients only when they can guarantee those patients will not die.

Comment: @Shog9 the reasoning you have just given are new to me. Maybe this could have been better communicated in the past ;). I am glad, we finaly found a good solution to the Triage problem.

Comment: @Shog9 The issue you describe - people demanding perfect judgement in triage, when triage is meant to be *quick* by design and need not be perfect - is orthogonal to whether we should tell users to mark things that specifically require additional information from the author as salvageable. To mutilate your metaphor further, if the burns unit is swamped with non-burned people who've been shot because all the medics have been taught to send them to the burns unit, that's a problem that needs fixing, and is independent of how good the medics are at assessing patients' survival chances.

Comment: @Shog9 And even if you think the two issues are not orthogonal - perhaps because you think reviewers are likely to underestimate the often-impressive psychic powers that editors can bring to bear when improving questions, and that "only improvable by the author" posts are usually actually improvable by anyone - that's still not an argument for introducing explicitly contradictory guidance. What's a new reviewer meant to think when we give them instructions, wait for their first review, then say (effectively) ***"NOTICE: You should be completely ignoring our instructions."*** It makes no sense.

Comment: They're not orthogonal, Mark: the burn unit in this increasingly grim metaphor is the close queue, which is the only other place to send questions that are not terrible but which may be missing key details. An unanswerable question leaving Triage wastes no one's time if the author edits it; it wastes maybe one person's time if it lands in the helper queue and someone *tries* to edit it but fails and it languishes until the system deletes it. It wastes 3-5 reviewers' time if it lands in the close queue.  See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344241

Comment: you might be interested in a similar request which suggests to show a warning like proposed here but by different criteria: [Show a confirmation popup to reviewers who pick Requires Editing at questions with many votes down and close](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363939/839601) (it also has a different purpose in that it aims to help not only reviewers but also moderators involved in handling troublesome triage decisions)

Comment: I've been thinking about this more, @gnat... I kinda wonder if something that just prompts for a description of what is needed might be more effective than a nag - "Please describe what is needed from an edit: "

Comment: interesting. I am not sure if I got it right, do you mean something like forcing reviewer to pick from predefined list of known legitimate kinds of edits? Possibly expanded with some free-form edit description for cases that didn't match the list

Comment: No, I'm thinking something akin to what we do for custom OT reasons, @gnat: `please leave a comment for potential editors. This post could use some editing to fix... [                    ]`

Comment: I see, thanks. This sounds very promising. At the very least this would make it so much easier for mods to handle troublesome reviews. It could also cause a big drop in amount of Requires Editing, can't tell if this is good or bad. Could you estimate how many of Requires Editing are currently okay - say, end with positively received questions?

Comment: Very, very few, @gnat. Depends on how you define it, but the simple definition - "scores > 0" - gives about 6-7%. OTOH, ~47% get closed and/or deleted, which is pretty solid for an option that doesn't expressly feed into the close queue.

Comment: I see. That means if amount of Requires Editing drops, it will likely do no harm. Which in turn makes your idea even more appealing. Have you thought of setting up some kind of [meta-tag:a-b-testing] for it?

Comment: It could easily do harm if those questions end up marked Looks Good or the close queue gets overwhelmed, @gnat

Comment: not quite I think. Great thing about unambiguous decisions like Looks Good and Unsalvageable is, these make it possible for moderators to decide on suspending abusive reviewers so the quality of triage reviews can be controlled. And as for overwhelming The Queue, I honestly can't believe it's possible, everything in there seems to be reliably designed to prevent this. Or, if you want even more safety, just require this comment only when triaging questions with many votes down and close.  Anyway, a-b-testing has been invented to aid in safely checking assumptions like that

Comment: ...on a further thinking, limiting the prompt to explain required editing to only questions with many votes down and close seems to fully address your concerns. First, there shouldn't be many such questions and second, since such questions are in close queue anyway, neither Looks Good nor Unsalvageable won't make a substantial impact. Not to mention that this way will likely be in line with your favorite approach of just in time learning

Comment: My only concern is that triage is supposed to be reviewed relatively quickly. If we are asking people for their feedback on why the post needs editing, then we might as just well edit it ourselves. Also, you can expect to see many comments such as _"This question is not clear enough"_ - which just defeats the purpose of adding it altogether.

Comment: Also, my recommendation to: _"...the close queue gets overwhelmed"_ is that if a question leaves triage with **Unsalvageable**, then we can make the close review queue only require 3 close votes rather than 5. While I understand that many (most) triage reviewers do not have the 3k rep to cast votes, it's in triage for a reason. If the outcome is unsalvageable, then allow that to mean something in the CV queue... It's relatively easy to reopen a question once the close issues are fixed.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs wrt asking for feedback I think here you have a good point against doing this indiscriminately. However in cases when triaged question already has many votes down and close (say 3 or 4), maybe we better trade some speed for reliability and ask reviewer to slow down a bit and think twice if they pick Requires Editing

Comment: @gnat absolutely I can agree with that. This way it doesn't always have to prompt the reviewer, but it will let the reviewer aware that the question has received negative feedback and their "Requires Editing" may or may not be the best option. Regardless, the _standard instructions_ language need to be updated regardless of any outcome, as it's currently deceptive to the reviewers.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs I hope that limited use of additional prompt will also help tame the problem of deceptive wording in generic triage guidance. I mean, reviewers who met more detailed explanation in that prompt would hopefully learn to apply it in other, "non-prompted" triage reviews. Correcting the wording for general case would of course be better but it somehow turned out rather difficult to do right (maybe because of need for it to be brief in that general case which naturally wouldn't hold in the case of specialized context dependent additional prompt)