# `Request Editing` description should be changed

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, triage, review-suspension

Today I got a ban from review. I didn't know why at first but I discovered that accessing manually the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) page will give you the explanation.

> Your review on [triage/24696115](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24696115) wasn't helpful. "Requires Editing" should only be used when other community users (like you) are able to edit/format the question into a better shape. If a question is unsalvagable and/or can only be improved by the author, please flag/vote to close or delete instead. For more information, see [meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389148](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389148).
>   Come back in 3 days to continue reviewing.

3 other guys in the same question clicked `Require editing` and by coming to meta I found out that a LOT of people do get soft ban for poorly judging the `Request Review` button as the meta post also suggest.

To me, this is become the explanation is not correct :

> Requires Editing for question that you can make clear and answerable
>   by editing

I think that an important part missing in the description. **WHO** has to do the edit ?

When I read this, I understand that the button is for a question is **NOT spam** but **unclear/incomplete** and that require editing to make it clear and answerable. So it sound like something you would click to notify that the question is OK, but in need to improve it by editing or adding information. It doesn't specify who has to do the edit, and I self assumed that it was some kind of notification for op to edit the question. It sound like this

> your question is good, but you can make it clear and answerable by
>   editing

Which is different from, the question can be edited by **OTHERS member** (op excluded) of the community to be clear and answerable by editing.

I don't know if you see the difference, but the first case it **doesn't exclude the op** from the edit, so it could be some kind of button to trigger a soft warning to the op in order to edit is own post (like, add some info, code ...). While, in the second case, since it **exclude the op**, you know that if the question has no information, then other people of the community will not be able to supply that.

I believe in order to have less review ban, and people confused about the reason, you should reformulate the description with.

> Requires Editing : use for question that **the community** can make clear and answerable by editing

Or something that clearly state that this will raise a community flag, and do **NOT** include any OP action.

**EDIT:** found a similar post thanks for the comment [Triage "Requires Editing" Notification to New Reviewers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363221/triage-requires-editing-notification-to-new-reviewers)

The fact that even in [the detailed description](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/3190532) the nuanced is pointed out *Can you imagine yourself (not the post's author)* is a proof that just adding this would already improve by a lot the short tooltip.

Comment: *WHO has to do the edit?* ... what do *you* think the word **you** means in *..question that you can make clear...*

Comment: also relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366580/578411

Comment: Actually this is the same, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363221/triage-requires-editing-notification-to-new-reviewers

Comment: yes indeed, all those long documentation post are explaining in details, but most people will read the little explanation only and get on with it. I don't say it's justified etc, but a small change could prevent all of this.

`you` means me, yes, but the nuance to you `the OP` is very light. Again, if you assume like me, that the button send a notification, it could be `you` the OP. `your post could be improved`

Comment: Also, the fact that in the link you post there is the same problem I pointed out `Can you imagine yourself (not the post's author)` is a proof that just adding this would already improve the tooltip a lot.