# Help and Improvement review queue not working

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage, help-improvement

This queue seems to have an awful lot of questions that should be closed.

Someone somewhere is neglecting to vote to close and just saying "Should be Improved" which to some extent all these questions should be improved, but they need to be improved by the original poster (OP), not by someone with editing privileges.

Here is the example that made me post to meta:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/7845862

This question either needs improvement by the OP or needs to be closed/deleted; asking me to edit it is no good.

I know about the 'This question is very low quality link', but my point is that too many questions of low quality are appearing in this Q.

Does the original poster see a note asking them to improve the question with more info?

My suggestion is that the "Should be Improved" button on the Triage queue is broken as it puts too many "Should be Closed" questions into the Help and Improvement queue.

Comment: `A similar question to this meta question has been marked as duplicate which is wrong it is not the same as the duplicate`... you may want to back that up a bit if you feel strongly about it.  It was closed by Community, which means the OP agreed it was a dup after the duplicate was proposed.

Comment: Ok, well this isnt a duplicate of that question, so I will remove the sentence.

Comment: Then you run the risk of getting question closed as a duplicate too.  I understand your issue and I think it is different enough, but just trying to acknowlege a potential duplicate by saying that a similar question isn't a dup without explaining why may not help.

Comment: related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290872/1843331

Comment: I guess the reviewer is not understanding the mechanism. "Must be improved; close in the meantime" is being written in this 'friendly' but ambiguous form "should be improved" which has misled reviewers.

Comment: @TimCastelijns related but not a duplicate.  I'm talking about trying to avoid these questions every making it to the 'needs to be improved' Q.  I think the wording or the mechanism needs to change.  'Must be Improved (by OP) ' or 'Should be Edited by Community'

Comment: Triage "should be improved". Even better, it "should be closed". This experiment _has failed_. The Stack Overflow world is more than ever awash in whack-a-mole questions that should never have made it to the floor in the first place. The bar for low-rep users to ask questions in the first place needs to raised across the board.

Comment: Huh. I always thought that "should be improved" included "ask back and forth questions getting the OP to clarify", not just "edit".

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit I wrote a long meta post on how we are encouraged everywhere else to close in the meantime, but in Triage we are only allowed to close if it's completely unsalvageable. But then I discarded it without posting because I remembered that the idea is that when triage is finished the "should be improved" questions don't get put on the site until they are improved. So putting them on hold until fixed doesn't actually make any sense in context - that's effectively what will already be happening.

Comment: This is happening to me A LOT lately. It seems like almost every question I flag as unsalvageable gets voted "should be improved", only to later to be (rightfully) put on hold. I just flagged a question from a user asking for career advice - primarily opinion based - but apparently reviewers think it can be improved :o

Comment: I was going through this queue today and ended up voting-to-close almost every single thing I ran across... definitely not working.

Comment: related: [What's the point of the “Very low quality” flag action, in “Help and Improvement” reviews? Where's the downvote / close option?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300131/whats-the-point-of-the-very-low-quality-flag-action-in-help-and-improvement)

Answer (score 81):

I agree, there are some fundamental problems with triage as it's working today. Far too many questions that should be closed are being voted as "Should Be Improved" and correctly-applied close flags are being invalidated as a result. Bad questions aren't being closed, and people are getting frustrated with their flags.

The problem is that there's a disconnect between what people read into "Should Be Improved" and what it actually does. That was the subject of [this Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289738/suggestion-for-rewording-of-triage-review-guidance), and Shog9's answer led to some changes in the flagging dialog, but I don't think that's addressing the core problem.

For someone unfamiliar with how the whole system works (most reviewers), you can see how they would look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7825089) and say "yes, that question should be improved". Technically, it should be improved, but it's a terrible question and should be put on hold until the unlikely event that it is improved. The community should not be responsible for improving it.

I think this still needs to be clarified in a way that makes it obvious to reviewers that "Should Be Improved" will remove close vote flags on it and kick it over to the community to edit.

The second part of the problem is one that Shog9 brings up [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289738/suggestion-for-rewording-of-triage-review-guidance/290915#290915). Triage of questions should be quick, and should be about identifying three core groupings: questions that are OK as they are, ones that the community can improve, and everything else (off topic questions, complete trash, or ones that require the asker's intervention).

Shog9 points this out in his answer, and has commented on this elsewhere, but SE saw a lot of people choosing the "Unsalvageable" option but not going through with it. That's because when you choose that option, it doesn't just move on, it requires you to choose a reason why something was unsalvageable. That's expanding triage from being just a quick separation of three classes of content to requiring you to do a diagnosis at the point of triage. It discourages people from choosing that option.

I think triage review needs to be reworded and simplified. "Should Be Improved" still has a place, but it needs to be reworded to reflect its purpose: sending things to be edited by the community. "Unsalvageable" should be a one-click action and should do something with the post to indicate the quality. Feeding into the close votes queue would be an option (maybe with a lowered threshold for close votes).

A fourth "Act on this now" option could be made available for those who want to do something with the content on the spot, populated with the selection of options from the current "Unsalvageable" menu.

Comment: This would really be nice ! I could almost never do a correct action on HIQ, because I have often found questions that did need improvement, that only Original Poster could improve, but that not clearly fell in one close reason.

Comment: Are all of these suggestions already included in a feature request? They sound like great improvements.

Comment: I would reword "Should be Improved" to "The community can fix this" and "Unsalvageable" to "Only OP can fix this," or something along those lines.