# Dispute on undisputably low quality question

Tags: discussion, disputed-flags

14 hours ago, I downvoted and flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010631/i-am-new-to-broadleaf-what-is-the-difference-between-the-core-and-admin-in-broa) awful question as "Very Low Quality".

The question's 1st revision was three poorly-spelled bad questions in one about Broadleaf Commerce, along with a gratuitous "*Please tell me the answer very urgent*". While I don't know much about Broadleaf, it absolutely reeks of *I didn't bother doing any research before asking* and *can i haz the codez???*. No code was provided that could help us understand the current state of his Broadleaf project. In any case I believe it fits both the name and description of VLQ:

> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

My flag is now disputed and I cannot reflag it as VLQ, but at least it's now got another downvote.

I'm assuming the dispute is because it was edited to improve the bad grammar, but what's left is *still* trash. It's had all of 17 views in the past 15 hours, of which several were mine, with two downvotes, no upvotes, no answers and no comments. And if the author is to be believed, his *"very urgent"* deadline has probably already expired. In my opinion, the grammar edit was putting lipstick on a pig; It's attempting to improve a question that is unsalvageable. So,

**Was I right to flag this as VLQ, and should this question indeed be removed?**

Comment: @BradLarson, I've had a further look at that [user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4710430), and his only other contributions are of similarly low quality: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557758), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29604022), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29650063). All three are essentially "I do X, I get Exception Y", with hardly any more detail. Instead of me flagging all that, could you please have a look yourself and then have a chat with him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the disputed flag is likely due to the fact that <s>the edit on the question took place to attempt to make it more on topic.</s>  [the question was marked as "Should be Improved" in the Triage Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7922108) per [Brad Larson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292215/dispute-on-undisputably-low-quality-question/292216?noredirect=1#comment187299_292216).  In spite of the edit done to improve the question I say it fell pretty short.

As for the question itself, it needs more help and clarification from the OP in order for it to make sense.  A few moments of Googling didn't bring any clarity as to what "core" meant to Broadleaf.

I don't know anything about the subject matter but I have a suspicion that someone *could* answer this question if it were made a bit clearer as to what the OP actually requires.  So, I don't think that VLQ is the right choice here.

Closing as "Unclear what you're asking"?  Absolutely.  It's not clear what they're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The question I pointed to has now been deleted, so what should I do about this meta question? It's outlived its usefulness and it's just accumulated several downvotes of its own in a short amount of time.

Comment: The question's been deleted *already*??  That's a pity.  Someone could've rescued that question instead.  The meta question can stick around; it isn't like the downvotes are going to impact your reputation.

Comment: Rather than being because of an edit, the flag was disputed because of Triage reviewers choosing "Should Be Improved": http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7922108 . This has become something of a problem lately: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291562/help-and-improvement-review-queue-not-working/291645#291645

Comment: Hmm.  Good to know @BradLarson.  I'll add that into the answer so it's apparent.