# Please rename the "Should be improved" button

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, triage

The HIQ is currently full of questions that indeed can be improved, as they don't contain enough details, however that's not the purpose of the HIQ.

<kbd>Should be improved</kbd> seems to be incorrectly interpreted by many reviewers. I don't say that it's not their fault as clicking on the `More` link reveals the explanation for each button, however many SO users (including me when I began reviewing questions from *Triage*) mistakenly use this button due to its label.

The best evidence to support this is the high amount of questions in this queue.

Comment: Do you have a proposed alternate wording?

Comment: Honestly, I don't, however I'm not that good at picking words either :)

Comment: Also, [I would argue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288779/rephrase-triage-help-text-for-should-be-improved-and-unsalvageable) that the `more` information isn't even that helpful.

Comment: Related: ["Help and Improvement review queue not working"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291562/help-and-improvement-review-queue-not-working)

Comment: Related: [Triage gray areas - what should we do when the question is borderline?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278461/2359271)

Comment: How about a "Who could improve it?" pop-up window when the button is clicked that allows you to choose from a list of suitable options: OP, Community, Me?

Comment: Being a new reviewer, I admit I misinterpreted it as "Should be improved by the author". Maybe "Improperly formatted" would be a possible choice instead? Note that the next category is called "Unsalvageable" which to me sounded too harsh for some of the questions that needed significant author's input but could be "salvaged".

Comment: Exactly my thoughts, @akhmed. Take a look at [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296730/958689) proposal, aswell, which goes beyond simple renaming.

Comment: I would add that this issue caused me to stop reviewing Triage. My flags frequently end up being "disputed" due to the majority of junior reviewers  saying "Should be improved" when they should flag instead.

Comment: Over a year later and several MSO questions complaining about the same thing. Why has this not bee done yet?

Answer (score 137):

I agree, the phrase "should be improved" is very ambiguous. I mean, which question couldn't benefit from some improvement? Especially ones which are in need of help to begin with.

Of course it *should* be improved. But *can* it be? And by whom? These are the two glaring issues with the phrase "should be improved".

Many times questions suffer greatly from a lack of information which could only be remedied by the OP of the question. In this situation, the question really should be improved to include that information, and it would often make it answerable and helpful - the problem is that this places a very large onus on a user who very easily could have posted a fire-and-forget question. In this scenario, "should be improved" does convey that there is something lacking that needs to be fixed, but doesn't properly convey that **only the OP can fix it**.

On the other hand, there are questions who actually have everything needed. The only problem is that they are obfuscated. Sometimes badly, sometimes not. These questions are also in need of improvement, so they should be improved while we are all in the mood to improve things. The problem is that in order to find one of these that you the average user can edit into shape, you have to wade (skip) through handfuls of the aforementioned type.

As a result, I propose some metrics to split these into different paths.

- **Asker Should Improve**
  This would address the times questions suffer from a lack of information. The community is powerless to fix these for the most part. What type of action this would take is up for debate. Perhaps a warning message for the OP on the question. Perhaps implicitly casts a close vote for unclear every n clicks from the queue. The main point is that as a user of the queue, we have reached a dead end. There needs to be way to filter these out aside from kicking them down the "should be improved" road.
- **Community Can Improve**
  This would allow the community a chance to fix posts which could actually be edited into an answerable form if given the chance by someone who was willing. Even when willing, if there is not enough information no amount of editing is going to help.

[image]

I have already addressed this when the queue was first released. At that time [my post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287473/1026459) was status-deferred. Perhaps it is now time to revisit the idea of refactoring this small aspect of the work flow.

Comment: If only the OP can fix, shouldn't you choose for unsalvageable in the first place. If we only rename the button 'Should be improved' to 'Community can Improve' that is a quick-win.

Comment: "Asker should improve" should kick the question out if the triage queye and cast an "Unclear what you are asking" close vote.

Comment: @rene - Well, sometimes there is no salvaging the post, even if the OP were to edit it. This can be the case when a post is very far off topic. However, there are cases I believe that the question is still salvageable, but only by the OP. For example, if they include most of a working example, but lack a data structure which gives everything context. Without the structure, the question cannot be answered, but by simply adding that context in, the question can stand on its own. Some questions are directly off topic and I think that is what unsalvageable is for, nothing can save those.

Comment: In that case *asker should improve* should show a dialog with an handful of canned comments, put that on the question and kick from any queue, only to be re-entered if the OP edited. No close votes/down votes/flags are cast. That is the sole purpose of *unsalvageable*

Comment: @rene - I like the idea of canned comments. Maybe with an option for other as well, or even the ability to simply edit the canned comment in the interface once chosen.

Comment: Well, your new buttons are in the wrong order. Aside from that, it would be "Community should improve", "Asker must improve", "Trash". Just to clearly delineate the difference between the renamed option, and the one you split out of unsalvageable.

Comment: @Deduplicator - Re-order ✓. Not sure about trash, or perhaps as rene points about above, maybe the idea of "Asker must improve" is being too optimistic about how attentive the OP is and that if it is on them to fix it, it may simply be "unsalvageable -> unclear".

Comment: What else but "trash" is left when you split "asker must improve" out of "unsalvageable" (by community)?

Comment: "Needs more information" instead of "Asker should improve"?  "Needs more information" is clear and concise and makes what the asker needs to do obvious.

Comment: @Yakk I guess that would work, if the only difference between "unsalvageable" and "asker should improve" is that it can be salvaged if there's more information.

Comment: @Yakk I think "needs more information" is not much better than current "needs improvement" - less ambiguous buttons are more likely they lead to desired effect.

Comment: @ascii exacly: if the asker posts an unsalvageable question, of course they need to improve.  But the narrow and common case of 'not enough information' gives the triage crew an easy diversion from 'let someone else handle it in some unspecified way'.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov "needs more information" is clear, and wouldn't send it to the community improvement queue.  The community cannot add information to a question (without reading the poster's mind), they can only clean it up.  It is a specific kind of improvement that the community cannot do, and apparently a source of crud in the improvement queue.  "needs improvements" sends it to the community to clean up.  So they are different in specific ways.

Comment: Nice, but I would wrap yours and Machavity idea: i) looks good, ii) community can improve (or "I can improve"), iii) close (wrap asker can improve, unsalvageable, etc; the close reason will tell if the asker can improve), iv) skip. The follow up actions would be, i) send to main page, ii) send to hiq, iii) close without showing in the front page, iv) does nothing.

Comment: I would correct "Community Can Improve" to "Community **Must** Improve" - the queue is really for questions that are not suitable for answering in their current form, but that still do have enough information (in principle) to be licked into shape by J. Random HIQer. "Can" implies that questions that need just a little touchup should go in as well, which is not really the case.

Comment: I am a bit surprised that this proposal is not supported by the devs. The idea that reviewers already decide if author interaction is required seems so obvious that many people suggested it when triage was introduced. Back then people already predicted that we will get into trouble by pushing questions into queues that cannot be improved by the community. Up to now I haven't seen a single argument invalidating that approach.

Comment: @cel: If you take a look, "looks ok" == "can be answered right away, though might not be good", "needs improvement" == "community can edit it into shape so former applies", "unsalvagable" == "community cannot edit it into shape". Trouble is the names are somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 7):

We've [changed the name](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302462/50049) to *Requires Editing*, with the following tooltip:

> This question could be good, but requires some time and attention of editors

"Should be improved" was far too ambiguous, almost *anything* on the site could use *some* improvement if you think about it long enough. This also more strongly emphasizes that you're giving other people work to do by pushing the button.

***This isn't, by any means, carved in stone.*** However, testing changes like this takes quite a bit of time per iteration, because questions that went into the queue yesterday aren't going to settle into their ultimate 'fate' for at least another few days.

I'm not, at this point, inclined to discourage sending things to the queue where it's pretty clear that only the author could provide the additional information. Data from this is still *extremely* noisy, but posts that went to the helper queue and only received a comment tended to do as well or better than posts that got edited in some samples, provided that they actually belonged there and weren't incomprehensible in addition to needing an edit only the author could provide.

This is for two reasons:

- Editing crap that didn't belong in the queue in the first place isn't going to help in many cases. The input is broken, and we're fixing that.
- While some askers find a link to the answer they need in the related column after posting and vanish, quite a few *do* stick around and remain responsive to comments.

Shog, Bluefeet and I will do another audit of 200 questions that went to the helper queue on Wednesday of next week (from the time the change was made). We'll determine if the questions belonged there, or if it should not have been sent there due to (a) being unsalvageable or (b) nothing being wrong with it to begin with.

We'll then see how much of a difference this made. I *suspect* that it's going to be substantially better. We'll then run the outcomes of the posts that went through the queue, and have much cleaner data, since we'll *hopefully* be much closer to being able to trust the input.

From there, we'll look at what's next, and that could be tweaking (or stopping) the recirculation of posts that went through the helper queue but didn't subsequently go anywhere back through the queue. We'll be able to see how many of these were just abandoned with much greater clarity.

With so many moving pieces, we *have* to test diligently, or we end up fixing it and not knowing how, or (worse) breaking it more and not knowing when. This will remain [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) until we've got more to report.

Comment: Do you have stats on how many people (and specifically newbies) actually use the 'related' sidebar?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Not yet. I can _infer_ it to a reasonable extent from our load balancer logs, enough to say "It's a thing, not just a theory", but I haven't set up a formal test for it. Planned, though.

Answer (score 1):

Tim Post has an earlier answer as to why this had been in review for a bit. However, time has clearly passed and this change has been made so I've updated the status to completed.