# Why are my flags disputed?

Tags: support, triage, disputed-flags

How come these 2 flags are disputed? Is there something I'm not understanding?

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864220/url-should-change-by-scrolling-one-page-wordpress-site
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886214/php-my-sql-record-locking-freezing

I flagged them both as unclear what they were asking.

So basically:

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The first one is not stating a question at all.

The second one gives no details at all.

Am I wrong here in some way?

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141292/what-is-the-difference-between-disputed-and-declined-flags

Comment: There just was another SO user that voted differently.  Probably somebody that's robo-voting through the Triage queue, that happens.  Picking through this kind of garbage turns most anybody into a zombie mouse clicker after a while.

Comment: Wow I actually have a lot of **** aged away or disputed like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369963/simple-website-visitor-count-in-codeigniter Worst thing is, no one is doing anything about it.

Comment: @HansPassant It's not just robo reviewers in triage.  A *lot* of users basically never mark anything as "unsalvagable", or basically only mark spam, marking anything with any problems as "should be improved".  The end result is that a huge portion of flags to close get declined even when the questions absolutely merit closure.

Comment: @Servy I have like at least 5 questions I flagged and got disputed and got deleted/closed afterwards anyway with like -5 votes.

Comment: @Loko Well the flags aging away is less surprising, and isn't so much the system being broken.  There simply aren't anywhere near enough people actually casting close votes to close everything that merits closure, or even everything that gets correctly flagged for closure.

Comment: @Loko Indeed.  That's the triage at work.  I feel like people need to be limited to like 5 Should Be Improved votes per day or something to prevent it being the default.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Because reviewers [don't know what "Should Be Improved" means](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294318/please-rename-the-should-be-improved-button):

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8473919
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8460414
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8460838

Most seem to believe that it means that the *poster* should improve the question, when in reality it is indicating that the *community* will be doing this improvement in the Help and Improvement queue.

This is [a common issue with Triage review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289658/lots-of-disputed-flags-since-yesterday).

Comment: Ban them.  Ban them all.  Until the end of time.  Until the end of the end of all times.  Ban.  Ban.

Comment: So I realize it's not exactly an easy task to teach reviewers what "should be improved" actually means, to get them to use it properly, and that whatever SE tries to do will likely take some time to make such a change, but can't we at the very least make marking as post as "should be improved" not dispute close flags, given that reviewers seem to get this wrong more often than they get it right.

Comment: @Servy - Agreed: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293457/we-should-clean-up-posts-that-should-be-improved-but-havent-been-and-wont-be/293463#comment189562_293463 . Per the rest of that discussion, I'm hoping that might be changed now that the initial evaluation period seems to be drawing to a close.

Comment: Maybe the term "Should Be Improved" is vague and confusing and the button should have a different text. "Should go to Improvement Queue" maybe.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt: "Make Some Other Poor Bloke Fix This Junk".

Comment: @NathanTuggy yeah, something like that

Comment: Interesting. However, note that the help information appearing in [Triage](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/) states. _Should Be Improved for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable_ Maybe a rewording would clarify this?

Comment: Yet another MSO question that, at heart, indicates that the current _Triage_ system is broken.

Comment: I agree with @fedorqui, the helps is totally misleading, and even sometimes when you read in Meta there are posts saying that if the post only requires few changes by the author it should be mark as should be improved. When a line is so vague, its meant to cause a lot of confusion.

Comment: More specifically: because the way the software works currently, "Should be improved" is interpreted to mean "Not unclear what you're asking". And yes @fedorqui, I'm seriously, seriously confused as to how so much time has gone by with that being the help text on Triage, and what appears to be a consensus that you're *not* supposed to follow the help text. At minimum, put a **WARNING: do not do what we're just about to tell you to do** :)

Comment: Honestly guys, I came to SO originally because I was looking for answers.  I silently read answers/responses the first hundred times I came here.  I began to see the site as a useful resource.  When I signed up and started answering questions I was confronted by what seems to be *some* individuals here who are drunk with their own power.  The ability to vote-down a question is given too soon, IMHO.  I'm a 30+ year I.T. guy.  I routinely deal with--what to me--are seemingly stupid questions and yet I try to play the mentor at work and kindly answer if I can... and hopefully educate.

Comment: @MichaelBlankenship - I'm sorry, but I don't know what your comment has to do with the subject under discussion. Did you mean to post this somewhere else?

Comment: @Brad No... that would be stupid if I'd done so.  The OP is flagging questions as unclear when to me the average question asked by the average user usually is.  I would suggest that it's up to the reviewer to choose to either guide the questioner into a more understandable question or to walk away--SO is a little heavy-handed with the attempts at moderation as I see it.  "More answers, less moderation" is what I'm hoping for.

Comment: @MichaelBlankenship - An IT help desk and the massive online repository of knowledge that is Stack Overflow serve very different audiences. The goal here is to have a curated collection of the best programming questions and answers. Downvotes are merely a quality measurement, but people take any criticism of their work very personally. The sheer size of this site means that we cannot hold the hand of every new user, and many people try to take advantage of us to do their work for them. At a help desk, you can deal with each person individually. That doesn't scale to a site this large.

Comment: @Loko Most people aren't diagnostic by nature.  They don't distill down the list of symptoms and iterate them for you, removing the superfluous.  The average question asked--even here--has a low clarity rate even to the experienced.

Comment: @MichaelBlankenship Maybe there's a mismatch between intentions and reality, here. As I understood it, close as "unclear" was supposed to be a way of directing the user towards improving their question, while preventing a ton of guessed answers from cluttering up the answer section in the meantime. If you have ideas for better ways to accomplish those goals, maybe you could write up a feature request?

Comment: FYI: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289658/lots-of-disputed-flags-since-yesterday/300787#300787