# Another Library/Tool Request Question Flag Disputed

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, disputed-review-audits, triage

I recently ran into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8481605) in the Triage queue which asks for a open-source library recommendation.  I flagged as Unsalvageable -> Off-Topic (it clearly asks for an off-site resource), but the other reviewers marked it as "Should Be Improved."  To me, this question can't be improved and is way off-topic.  What am I missing?

EDIT: The question was just put on hold by Mureinik and Brad Larson, so thanks guys.

Comment: Nothing. The other 3 reviewers were wrong ;)

Comment: *whistles* http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297159/why-are-my-flags-disputed/297163#297163

Comment: @DavidPostill You should probably repost your comment as an answer ;)

Comment: Y'all know you can close a question as duplicate, right? ;)

Comment: Simple solution:  auto-ban anyone who clicks "Should be improved", regardless of the quality of the question.  It's like a honeypot for bad reviewers.

Comment: Hijacking post to try to get [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30561090/3488231) closed as well. My flag has been "pending" for more than half a month. /cc @BradLarson

Comment: Somebody beat those reviewers half to death.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I really wish they would rename the buttons already in triage.  You did the correct review and the others were mistaken. <kbd>Should Be Improved</kbd> means we can fix it.  If only the OP can fix it then it is <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd>.

I did find that once you can cast close votes you don't have to worry about the disputed flags showing up anymore.  Also the close vote doesn't get removed from the question if it is "disputed" as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8451961)

Answer (score 9):

**" What am I missing?"**

Nothing. The other 3 reviewers were wrong ;)