# Flagged question as "very low quality" got disputed because the edits. Should I re-flag them?

Tags: discussion, disputed-flags

I flagged some questions because the OP just provides not much information. I just wanted the OP give some kind of explanation about his issue.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38951082/photon-master-server-license-could-not-load-at-local-host)

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849721/augmented-reality-app-with-user-defined-target-using-unity)

[or this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224471/how-to-resolve-soomla-iap-unity-ios-plugin-invalidcastexception)

I read [Why are my flags disputed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297159/why-are-my-flags-disputed) and [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag) threads where I found quite interesting information.

However, My question is since the questions got some minimal edits -I want to think so...- should I re-flag them? I don't want get banned or lose my privileges for being stubborn.

Comment: Don't flag these as "very low quality", flag them as "should be closed".

Comment: All three went though the triage queue with the consensus of "requires editing", disputing your flags. I think the reviewers need to be taught what "requires editing" is actually for.. And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13339899) is just bad..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flag questions as "very low quality" if they are completely unsalvageable and warrant immediate deletion.

If you just believe they should be closed, and have any chance at all of being edited into decent shape, use a standard close vote or close flag. Your flags were disputed by these reviews: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/13341831 , https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/13307897 , https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/12921584 , not due to any edits.

Reviewers have a tendency to interpret the "requires editing" review reason as "requires editing by the asker" not the intended "requires editing by the community", so you'll often see "very low quality" flags on things that possibly could be edited into shape be disputed by review. This is less likely for complete trash that anyone can agree should be deleted.

That first question was worthy of a "very low quality" flag, and I deleted it (another moderator handled the reviewers involved). The second one was probably best addressed by a close vote, since there's an outside chance that could be made answerable. The third is pretty clearly covered by a close reason, so I closed that.

Comment: Through in theory what Brad says is true, the system isn't coherent with it. A VLQ flag will push the question to the Triage queue where other users can pile on, or dismiss it. I'm surprised that one of those posts went to triage twice, thrice to the H&I, and only once to the close queue... most of the time it went to the triage the users selected "Need editing" for a question describing a problem without a single LoC!!! [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38849721/timeline).

Comment: *Reviewers have a tendency to interpret the "requires editing" review reason as "requires editing by the asker" not the intended "requires editing by the community"* I remember there was a mod handling out review bans to all the reviewers that have this tendency... any hope that they are corrected?

Comment: @Braiam - As long as people are confused by the wording of that option, [or the guidelines behind it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319128/triage-review-queue-inconsistent-guidelines-for-requires-editing), it's difficult to change the behavior of that many people. Audits don't seem to be as effective here as with other review types.

Comment: Meh, just bring out the stick... they will learn...

Comment: The fact that something went through H&I _three times_ shows that H&I isn't helping at all. Most "reviews" I see there are just minimal edits, and no explanation whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed clarification. For now on I'll keep in mind what to do. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: `Reviewers have a tendency to interpret the "requires editing" review reason as "requires editing by the asker" not the intended "requires editing by the community"` -> Perhaps that is because the help box says: "**Requires Editing**: for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable"... Really, no one can blame the reviewers one iota for misinterpreting this. It's counter-intuitive and the help text is worded confusingly. You need to dig up some meta-post to get the **real** help instructions...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Even just removing "the author or" from that would be a huge improvement, since that's flat out incorrect. Does this just need a feature request?

Comment: Oh nevermind, there's one [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321895/change-triage-guidelines-for-requires-editing) but it's been closed as a duplicate of a larger feature request.

Comment: @BSMP [Already happened.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289738/6083675)

Comment: @Laurel - Yes, that's the larger feature request the other was closed as a dupe against.

Comment: Handing out review bans for people who have an obvious and understandable confusion about the wording seems...unnecessarily harsh? I mean, it's not like these people are picking the "no action needed" option like [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13339899) did. They have a legitimate argument that the question needs editing. Instead of trying to educate one user at a time, wouldn't it be easier just to change the wording of the option in the queue? I know, it's radical, but not everyone reads Meta.

Comment: I didn't realize how timely my previous comment might have been. If [this guy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332542/why-could-reviewing-questions-with-unobvious-belonging-be-a-reason-for-banning-f) was manually banned because he chose "requires editing" on a question that... ***clearly requires editing***, then I have to *seriously* object to [this new policy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332542/why-could-reviewing-questions-with-unobvious-belonging-be-a-reason-for-banning-f#comment383858_332542). Fix the UI, don't fix the users.

Comment: @CodyGray - In general, I shy away from bans on "requires editing" reviews like the one you highlight there, but I do think review bans were appropriate for the first question, which was completely unsalvageable and even got ["No Action Needed" reviews on it](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13339899). It's clear to me that reviewers are still confused as to the meaning of the "requires editing" review option, and that something needs to change here. However, I don't think even a confused interpretation of that option excuses the reviews on that first question.