# What to do about posts that ask for help creating code

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts, disputed-flags

I was recently reviewing First Posts and Triage questions on SO. I found myself stumbling across a few that sounded something like that:

- "How do I make a taskbox in Java"
- "How can I create a dropdown in HTML"
- "How do I make a countdown in JavaScript"

Those are just random examples I made up to show my point. Those questions are asking to show them how to create something, give them ready code or directly code it for them.

I tried flagging them as off-topic/ **Asking For Off-Site Resources**, however those flags were disputed or even once declined. 
I tried again with **too broad** and **very low-quality**. Again, those were always disputed.

Now my question: Should I flag those questions, and if so with which flag. If not, what should I do? Just leave them as they're fine and answer them, or what action should I take?

Comment: The main thing I think you are having an issue with is: [the triage queue is broken](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294318/please-rename-the-should-be-improved-button)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that [disputed flags aren't the same as declined flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212508/can-i-get-rid-of-disputed-flag-stat-if-it-turned-out-to-be-correct/212511#212511)

Since we don't have any example questions, just titles, these should be flagged as either

> too broad

or off-topic as

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Now, **especially** if it is a new user you also may comment and link to the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and suggest, politely, that they read about what types of questions to ask here and how. I have an auto comment saved for these situations and one regarding downvotes (since users often ask why they are downvoted).

Comment: Yeah. But my point  is, all of my flags were disputed when tagging as too broad. So I should just flag as my code is not working even if there's no code shown and the question is just asking for code to be shown?

Comment: Check the link in my answer. Disputed doesn't mean others disagree and it's rejected. It means something else happened to make it possibly invalid. Either close reason is fine if they are just asking for code.