# Send low-quality posts that "should be an edit to the question" to the "Help & Improvement" queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, edits, help-improvement

I'll be honest, I don't spend a lot of time in the [Help & Improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/) review queue because it looks like a lot of the stuff that I find in there can only be fixed by the original author.  Based on [this post from Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288387/1288), that's probably because everything from the H&I queue comes directly from [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/), where someone clicked on the Requires Editing button.

One specific kind of post that I frequently see in the [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/) queue is an "answer" where the OP posts their code as a follow-up post that should have been an edit to the question. The Edit button on those currently opens the answer in an edit page, which is the right behavior most of the time, but not for these posts.

These seem like a pretty easy edit decision to make if they're presented in the right way. Can these posts be sent to the Help & Improvement queue when people vote to delete them with the reason "should be an edit to the question"? Additionally, can the reason the post is in the H&I queue be put at the top of the page, where the text "We need your help editing questions to be clear and answerable" is currently displayed?

Comment: I don't spend much time in that queue either for the same reason you state. Perhaps if there were some improvements made to the feature it would be more efficient at accomplishing its goal.

Comment: @TravisJ Yeah, I think it would be a lot more useful if we could identify a few specific things that can be edited by the community (and present that information), rather than the current catch-all system that it seems to be now.

Comment: (Hopefully some people who actually use that queue can offer some tips as well.)

Comment: Instead of forcing this to go through the review queue, or in addition to, could we do a "should be an edit" flag on answers where they are the OP that will send it right to the HIQ?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, that's a good idea. If they can be identified earlier, they might as well go directly to the H&I queue.

Comment: @NathanOliver - [I proposed that same idea](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294321/1026459), *twice* actually, when the feature was first released.

Comment: @TravisJ And look at that,  I already up voted it.  If I stole your idea I did not mean to.  It is a good idea :)

Comment: @NathanOliver - Oh, that wasn't my intention. I was just trying to say your idea was good (and that twice I also tried to go in that direction as well).

Comment: Most of the "reviews" that I see in H&I are just very minor edits, and no explanation on how SO works at all. I'm in favor of this feature-request, but I believe the H&I queue needs some serious improvement first.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I agree, this is only one step out of several that would need to be taken to improve the utility of that queue. If they implement this, it might go from 1 out of 20 items that I know what to do with to 2 out of 20.