# Allow special comments to be passed to H&I queue from Triage

Tags: feature-request, triage, help-improvement

I was just reviewing a few posts in a row in Triage that all (hopefully) got sent to the Help and Improvement review queue and was annoyed to realize that, in the time it took to determine that I should hit <kbd>Should Be Improved</kbd>, I had already figured out the basics of what would need to be done to fix the question. Well, really I was annoyed that this understanding was wasted as soon as I finished the review.

So what if it wasn't wasted? **What if we had a special comment/summary/whatever field to be entered upon hitting <kbd>Requires Editing</kbd>?** This field should *only* be displayed to Help and Improvement reviewers and would presumably be optional. As a bonus, the additional friction/required thought would doubtless reduce the number of thoughtless queue entries by some small but non-zero amount, which can only be helpful at this stage. And, of course, Help and Improvement reviewers would have a better idea what they should at least start with; sometimes it's not really obvious why Triage pushed things in (and if there's no good reason, hit the VLQ link!).

It would not be very useful to be limited *only* to a predefined list, since often you'd want to say "rephrase X in terms of Y" or similarly specific instructions, but showing previous reviewers' comments/instructions in the dialog and letting you agree with them would almost certainly be of value, and from there it's just a small step to having a list as a starting point that can then be added to.

As a further refinement, these special comments (at least if only one was chosen) could be used to pre-populate the summary/comment field in Help and Improvement for the reviewer to tweak before finishing their edit. ("Did I actually fix that like this comment I'm about to post says I should and did?")

Comment: This might make reviewing in H&I easier, as well: I haven't done a lot of reviewing there, but when I have I've sometimes [wondered _why_ the stuff that's there is there](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291562/). Annotations from those voting to add to H&I might aid the people trying to do the Helping and Improving.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Yes, I should probably have specifically mentioned that; I am sometimes careless in assuming others will see the second- or third-order benefits that will result from something.

Comment: If this was to happen it would be nice if there was a selection of canned responses for very common issues.  Something like Code needs formatting, Spelling / Grammar needs improvement.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I could add those to the list I tacked on as an afterthought. However, I think only questions with really substantial spelling or grammar errors, or really painfully unformatted code, would belong in H&I, so making sure the predefined options don't lead people to throw posts in just because they misspelled one word seems wise.

Comment: I also feel that there is a large misunderstanding of triage reviewers. The should be improved seems to imply other things than clarity and stuff like that.

Comment: I support this. The triage reviewer spends some time analysing the post and its problems. Currently the H&I reviewer has to repeat all the analysis thus wasting time and effort.

Answer (score 43):

A more fleshed-out list of predefined options to start with:

> #### What edits does this question require before it can be readily answered?
>
> - Overhaul its substantial spelling/grammar/formatting errors
> - Rewrite the title to represent the core of the problem
> - Remove useless and mistaken tags and add crucial, relevant tags
> - Incorporate important information from comments
> - Other (add a summary explaining what reviewers should focus on):

Unusually, I think this should be a list of checkboxes, not option buttons.

Comment: related: [Triage guidance for Requires Editing: “Pull code in from hosting site linked in question”, how it is handled in H&I?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364714/839601)