# How does the Triage review queue work?

Tags: support, faq, review-queues, triage

I recently got the privilege to review questions in [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage), and I'm pretty sure I'm already doing it wrong.

I've read some of the Q&A about the Triage review queue here on Meta, but I was wondering if there is a guide explaining how it works and how I should be reviewing.

What do the four review options mean, what should I do if I'm unsure what action to take, and how many Triage reviews can I perform per day?

What should I do if I make mistakes? Is there any recourse?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: Related: [Why was I suspended from reviewing for selecting “Requires Editing” in Triage?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389148/why-was-i-suspended-from-reviewing-for-selecting-requires-editing-in-triage)

Comment: How do posts get into Triage in the first place?

Comment: @DanielWiddis Through VLQ flags or through some unknown heuristic when the question is posted (questions which score below the heuristic threshold are put into the queue, questions scoring above are given full visibility on the homepage)

Comment: @10Rep, I disagree that featuring this is *very* helpful. Few hundereds of users may read this and even learn, but as soon as this is unfeatured you will still have a problem. The constant need to route new users here probably indicates some problem there. Perhaps triage UI needs a change. Imho featured is for something what needs *discussion* or a kind of announce (when there is no way to get new information). Necro-featuring wiki questions periodically is interesting idea, but there could be a better way.

Comment: @Sinatr I agree with you on this. There's another deeper problem with reviewing. Users do not understand which Questions are OK and which should be closed. Triage routes a lot of wrong reviews to the Help & Improvement queue, and that makes them very visible wrong reviews. But there are lots of posts going wrongly through review and never closed. Some come from Triage, but I believe more come from the First Posts queue, where only *one* reviewer makes the call. The deeper issue is the route cause, in my opinion.

Comment: @Sinatr I agree the Triage UI needs a change, which is why I quit triage. But SE doesn't seem to want to do anything as of now. Instead, they are bombing new things on us that most people think is junk. So a moderator simply did the next best thing, which is to raise awareness. It's not going to fully solve the problem, but after looking at this post I understood what my mistake was when I was doing triage. There is definitely a better way, which is for the company to take action.

Comment: @DanielWiddis Also, if a post receives a 'Looks OK' review in Triage, you can 'dispute' the review i.e. push it **back** into Triage by flagging the question as *Very low quality*.

Answer (score 1218, accepted):

The primary goal of Triage is to *quickly* sort potentially problematic posts into categories that can be routed elsewhere. Many people have expressed confusion over how to use Triage, as the queue has evolved considerably over time.

Here are some rules of thumb based on the review options available:

### Skip

If you aren't sure what should happen to a question, **Skip it** and move on to the next one. This should be your default option: there's no penalty for skipping, and it immediately makes the question available for others to review, so if you don't think you can make a good decision *quickly* (within, say, a minute), **Skip it!**

Common reasons to Skip include:

- an unfamiliar technology, and not *blatantly* unsuitable for the site (I *dare* you to try judging the validity of VHDL tagged questions if you've never worked with it).
- the prose is hard to understand but not necessarily impossible (English written by folks who don't often write English can be extremely confusing for those not accustomed to it).
- extremely long and detailed, combined with either of the above...
- ...or you're just in a hurry and were hoping to find an obvious spam post to flag before heading out for lunch.

Remember: [There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip)!

### Flag (question is spam, rude/abusive, or should be closed)

Use **Flag** for ***incomplete and/or off-topic questions*** which should be closed.

#### Blatantly-inappropriate questions

Is it spam? A rant about nothing productive? The output of someone's cat dancing merrily across their keyboard? Not in English? Easy enough: choose **Flag**, and flag or vote to close appropriately. (At 3k some of the options become votes instead of flags, but the UI doesn't change much.)

Of course, if you *think* it's the work of a cat but suspect it *might* actually be a valid Perl regex that got mistagged somehow... Skip, so someone else can have a look.

#### When you know something about what you're reading

Even questions that aren't *blatantly* inappropriate for the site can still be Flagged if there's simply no way they can generate a useful answer. Usually, judging these questions will require at least some basic knowledge of the technologies involved though, and you'll want to read the question carefully — the good folk answering Ruby questions won't appreciate you flagging stuff simply because all the Gem names appear to have been produced from a set of rather twee Markov chains. Again, if you're not sure, *hit Skip!*

You should **Flag** a question for any reason you would flag a question. These include, but are not limited to:

- It's a duplicate.
- It is extremely broad, requesting answerers to implement an entire system ("I want to build a Facebook, but for dogs") or write a textbook ("Can someone explain functional programming, and concurrency, and asymptotic notation and also three other questions on my test before tomorrow?") or both ("I'm new to programming, and want to write my own operating system on x64 - where should I start?").
- It is written in a [language other than English](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/839601) (even if it is a clear and answerable question for those who understand it).
- Anything that has no direct connection to programming or software design ("I want to share football scores with my team, but I'm locked out of my Slack account; halp?")
- It is Primarily Opinion-based: This can sometimes be tricky, as questions which require some level of professional, experience-based opinion are OK. Questions are off-topic when answers will be based primarily on opinions (e.g. "are tabs or spaces better for indenting").
- Any reason in the community-specific (off-topic) sub-pane of the close-vote or close-flag dialog, including:

  - About general computing hardware and software
  - About professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration
  - Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more
  - Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
  - Belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network (and is off-topic on Stack Overflow)
  - Blatantly off-topic (only listed on the close-flag dialog; for a close-vote use another valid reason, or a custom reason)
  - Other, custom reasons (only listed on the close-vote dialog)

That last one deserves a note: if a question is definitely off-topic but is quite well-written *and* on-topic for another Stack Exchange site, you can flag/vote for migration using Flag → **off-topic** → **belongs on another site** (or a custom moderator flag if the necessary site isn't in the list of sites). Alternately, just leave a comment noting the existence of the appropriate site and close as off-topic.

### Needs Community Edit

Use **Needs Community Edit** only for ***complete and on-topic*** questions which simply require a cleanup.

#### Needs Community Edit = Needs an editor

Can you imagine **yourself** (not the post's author) editing the question to improve its current state? How about some other random editor with perhaps more knowledge of the specific area, or more patience for lousy writing, or both?

If you *don't know* whether the question can be fixed by editing alone — perhaps you've never worked with the technologies involved and simply can't tell if it's a reasonable question for topic-experts — then **Skip**; there are other questions that need your attention more.

If *you're sure* that this question can be fixed through editing alone (see also *Addendum: Bad Triage Review* below) then hit **Needs Community Edit**. This keeps the post visible on the site and may add it to the <s>*Help & Improvement*</s> *First Questions* review queue, allowing **other** editors to find and improve it.

#### Reasons for choosing Needs Community Edit

- Overhaul its *substantial* spelling/grammar/formatting errors
- Rewrite the title to represent the *core* of the problem
- Remove *useless* and mistaken tags and add *crucial*, relevant tags
- Incorporate *key* information from comments
- Incorporate *key* information from mistaken self-answers (assuming you can see these, which is not usually the case)

(These reasons are borrowed from [another post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294880/allow-special-comments-to-be-passed-to-hi-queue-from-triage/294974#294974).)

#### Reasons for NOT choosing Needs Community Edit

**Do not choose "Needs Community Edit" if you *know* the question can only be made answerable with clarifications or additions from its author.** The correct option for that is "Needs Author Edit."

For example, if an [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) question asks for an explanation of errors found in logcat, *but omits specific errors and/or logcat listing*, the question doesn't require editing — it requires more information, so choose **Needs Author Edit** → **Needs details or clarity**.

A question is also **Needs Author Edit** if the code, error message, or other crucial information is only present as an image (or image link)! It's the author's and **not the editor's job** to include all relevant information as text. The same applies to questions which link to code repositories without including the critical code sections or a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in their post. Images and links should only ever serve as references or enhancements of what's already being stated completely as text in the question's description.

### Looks OK

First, there's a bit of a special case here: Duplicates. A clear, well-written question might still be a duplicate, and the last thing you want to do is to [dispute Duplicate flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289658/lots-of-disputed-flags-since-yesterday/300787#300787) by choosing Looks OK if it *is* a duplicate. So always read the comments *first*: scroll to the end of the question, and if you see "Does this answer your question?" (formerly: "Possible duplicate") in the list, either mark it as a duplicate yourself (if you can confirm that the comment is accurate) or Needs Community Edit if the author has provided some clarification in the comments but hasn't yet edited the post; choose Looks OK only if you're certain the question is *not* a duplicate. As always, **Skip** is a fine option here if you simply don't want to take the time to look at duplicates.

[image: The "Does this answer your question?" auto-comment indicates there is at least one close vote but also look for comments suggesting a question is very similar, a duplicate, or has the answer the asker needs.]

If the question is clear, well-written and unique, hit **Looks OK**. If you're the 3rd person to choose this option, you'll get the chance to vote on the question following your review — go ahead and do so! (You can always vote by clicking through to the normal question page of course, but since exceptionally good questions are so rare Triage gives you a chance to do this without leaving the queue).

If it's a halfway decent question but not amazing, or if some editing would be nice to clean up some minor errors or rough spots, but it's just about as answerable without any, just hit **Looks OK**.

If it's kind of a boring or useless question but it doesn't really need to be closed or removed, hit **Looks OK** (and downvote if you're the 3rd reviewer).

### Needs Author Edit

Use **Needs Author Edit** for questions that need more information or clarity from the author.

#### Reasons for choosing Needs Author Edit

This is a new option that duplicates some of the functionality of the **Flag** option, but makes it much clearer that a vote for this option is a vote for sending the question back to the author.

Choose **Needs Author Edit** if:

- The question doesn't have enough information to be answered as-is
- You understand the question topic and the question they're asking is unclear or ambiguous
- Key information/code in the question is in screenshot form only
- The question is too broad

---

#### Addendum

**Queue limits**

The limit of 20 reviews/day is common to all review queues on all sites and does not change with reputation, time spent on site, badges, helpful flags, review counts, audit pass rates, or much of anything except the queue overflowing: if there are more than [150 reviews backlogged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science/320971#320971), all reviewers will have 40 reviews/day in that queue. (♦ moderators do not have review limits.)

**Recovery of a Bad Review**

You had too much coffee, you finger twitched, and by mistake you wrongly clicked on the **Needs Community Edit** (or **Looks OK**) button when you actually wanted to click on the **Flag** button. What can you do?

1. You cannot change or undo your review.
2. Instead, go back to the question itself and ***flag it as you should have during the review***.
3. If flagging doesn't work for you, or if there's some other concern, then join the [Bad Stack Overflow Review Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208985/bad-stack-overflow-reviews) and discuss your bad review there to find a resolution.

Comment: How would you categorize questions asking to solve their homework by only posting the entire problem description without any information on what they have tried or any specific problem? Is it *too broad* or rather *off topic*? If *off topic* then which of the options, because none of them seem to match.

Comment: @anddero: Too Broad is usually best; a problem statement for homework is not an actual question per se, but only background information for what *should* be a more narrowly focused and specific question that comes up in the process of solving homework. But to some extent it doesn't matter too much: a homework dump is just generally terrible quality, so any close reason that is more or less applicable can be slapped on there to just get out of the way.

Comment: How do you categorize people who don't post any try/code ? Too broad too ?

Comment: @MaximeGirou: If the question is asking too much, flag as too broad; if it doesn't make sense without the relevant code, unclear, or the MCVE custom reason. But not all questions even need any code at all.

Comment: Hitting "Looks OK" on any post with "rough spots" is liable to end up hitting an audit question that gets you banned from the review queue.  The whole process feels like a minefield.

Comment: Might be a nice article, but it requires a much higher level of English than a non-native English speaker gets by programming and reading documentations. The little difference from "maybe" to "probably" is not easy to grasp, or idioms like "the work of a cat" either. Please try to stick to some more scientific language. I consider myself to speak fluent English - but I'm unable to understand Shakespeare in English - and this shouldn't be necessary for stackoverflow.

Comment: I really do think the first word in the answer should be  a big NO.
I searched for this for quite a while and it would be nice to actually get an answer to the question, as there is nothing in the help centre.

Comment: @Xan-KunClark-Davis: This *is* the official guide to the Triage queue; it's linked directly from the queue itself. (There are reasons it's not in the help center, but those aren't terribly important. The most important thing is that SO staff have recognized this as official.)

Comment: I'm still not sure on how to triage questions from someone who didn't try anything at all. Like "I want [this code] to do [this]. Please do it for me" or "I want to convert [this code] to [this language]. Please do it for me". For now I I just skip them but PLEASE handle this case in the guide.

Comment: most of the posts i get in my triage queue are about technologies i don't use and therefore i can't add value. can i apply filtering somehow?

Comment: @Camusensei "Unsalvageable", needs more focus (too broad in the old parlance used in the answer, here).

Comment: @DaveKielpinski I don't believe you can on Triage - you can on the other queues though.

Comment: @Camusensei These are "Unsalvagable" and could be flagged as "Needs more focus". On a general point, the Triage queue seems to be on a hair-trigger for temp-banning; twice in the last month I've had one-week total queue bans...

Comment: thanks @Legorooj, guess i'll be sticking to reviewing the other queues then

Comment: These tips, and especially the first rule about "Skipping" and the link to [There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip) Should be on the Triage page for all potential triage-ers.

Comment: I for one am glad that these triage Q&As have come back to life, because for the first time I actually have a sense for how to do triage. I am still wary of it, but at least I now have a mental picture of what my job would be and I've triaged one or two and felt I was doing the right thing.

Comment: Damn you!  I've got the idea of a cat or regex quiz stuck in my mind! :):)  (Although I don't really think a cat could make anything that could be confused for a regex.)

Comment: @KenY-N: “On a general point, the Triage queue seems to be on a hair-trigger for temp-banning”—I avoid the Triage queue for that exact reason. I usually skip, but I do try to vote if I’m above 80% confident. And yet that’s still just 5-10 votes away from being on the wrong side of a judgment call. (With the mediocre quality of most posts, I’m rarely above 90% confident.) First Posts are much safer, and provide an opportunity to help welcome new contributors and coach them on how to best use the site. That said, with each test or suspension I develop a better heuristic for those judgment calls.

Comment: I see a loophole in Skipping questions that written in poor English that can be understood, but still is broken. If all of us stick to the rule, I feel that the post will never exit triage. Thus, Skipping is just procrastinate, until someone will finally say Looks Ok to broken English, or Requires Editing, again for broken English. Doesn't this loophole defy the purpose of community driven reviews, putting work on the shoulders of experienced reviewers, as newcomers are guided towards Skip 'em all? Shouldn't Broken English default to Requires Editing?

Comment: Moderators are draconian in banning the reviews for marking the question as Requires Editing. Imagine the case: the question *MAY* have a valid answer being a little vague. One option is to mark this question as Unsalvageable to request the author for clarification. However there could be multiple reasons of the problem, valid answer exist! Now imagine that this question is written in a poor English. I guess the question is still salvageable but requires editing. This however puts me into the risk of being banned for marking an "Unsalvageable" question as "Requires Editing".

Comment: After I had received my reviewer privilege yesterday, I read this thread earlier today. Then, I did a couple of Triage reviews (about 20 or so, plenty of Skip in between when I was unsure). Apparently, I had misunderstood parts of the descriptions above. So I didn't get a warning or something, but a direct ban. Draconic? Yes, they are. For the first mistake (or, the first day making one or potentially multiple mistakes), I got banned for > 1 month. I cannot recommend anybody to take part in Triage reviews and put at risk the own account for "nothing".

Comment: Please note also that the on-topic/off-topic question may be not as sharp as the descriptions sound, at least some questions leave a lot of room for discussion. While the in-or-out discussion on the *question* does get this room, a dissident reviewer is sanctioned without any discussion or appeal. I have the impression that this is utterly disproportionate.

Comment: @DaemonPainter that is exactly what happened to me. I have been banned for 4 months for using "Requires Editing" instead of "Unsalvageable" on a question which had poor English but already had a comment of someone trying to help (it could easily be understood tbh).

Comment: Before doing any (triage) reviews I actually spent my time on reading this documentation ___carefully___ but I still got banned for choosing __Requires Editing__ over __Unsalvageable__ in a matter of days :/ So why is that? This sentence "How about some other random editor with perhaps more knowledge of the specific area, or more patience for lousy writing, or both?" under Requires Editing is misleading and leaves room for interpretation. There are many (bad) questions (with missing information) which could be recovered by such a (patient) random editor.

Comment: I also think an important section or warning is missing in this document: ___Consequences of Misjudging a Question___. 1) Know your judgment is final (you cannot undo hitting the wrong button by mistake) – except for Skip. 2) A wrong judgment (Requires Editing over Unsalvageable) results into tedious, manual work for the moderators to recover from it 3) You're definitley going to be banned from using the review system for X days for making a single judgement mistake. // Such section would also help to correct the (maybe too carefree) tone of this document IMO.

Comment: @IvoMori Feel free to add that section in yourself; it's community wiki. And thanks for the warning, I'll stay off of any review queues for a while :)

Comment: Does OP get to see comments or reviewer's justification when question's marked as Unsalvageable? I just marked a "Why can't I find a tutorial on [two common technologies]?" question as Unsalvageable. It was the author's first post, and I don't mind tossing a couple links at them, but I want them to know why I rejected it.

Comment: It seems like if anyone doesn't already know what these options mean and wants to avoid getting banned (whatever the implication of that is), they should just avoid the triage queue altogether. Basically echoing @ChuckAdams . I just want to add when I am reading this answer the policy seems quite hostile to folks who are volunteering to improve the community.

Comment: I've seen Triage for the first time. I had no idea what to do with it. After reading through this, I'm not actually much wiser, except that it is being made very, very clear that doing this is a mistake for 99% of the people out there. Literally stopped reading at the threat of being banned for making a mistake.

Either the wording needs to be improved, or the rules. In any case can I only recommend not to participate in this, unless you're absolutely 100% certain that you know what you're doing in respect to the topic of the question.

Comment: Perhaps a flow-chart describing how to do reviews to help making judgement calls? It's not obvious to me how to do this as far too much are IMO corner cases. Like for example: A question is in poor English, but it's salvageable by editing. After spending some time with it you realize it's still not a high quality question. I.e. the review needs more than one judgement according to the guide. Which one do you pick?

Comment: In "Triage" and "First Posts", the posts come relating to all fields or tags. It would be better that there got to some filter criteria according to the tags. Only those tags' posts are supposed to come for review for the reviewer.

Comment: @Sh.Imran in First Posts you can filter by tag, but not Triage.

Comment: I don't understand the recommendation to skip for "extremely long and detailed" questions: at some point someone needs to take a decision. If a question is valid and well-researched, but includes 500 lines of code, should it go to "editing" to keep only the relevant lines, or "unsalvageable" to make the author write a minimal example? Or should it be accepted as long as it's not combined with another problem?

Comment: @Alexlok 500 lines of code will most likely invalidate the minimal part of an MCVE, i.e. flag as "Needs debugging details" (formerly Needs MCVE), since it's the OP's job to reduce the code to only the necessary bit to represent the problem. Don't edit someone else's code (there are only very few exceptions to this rule). As to your point itself: yes, at some point someone will have to review those long and detailed questions. Preferably someone with domain knowledge, as they can determine whether it's an OK question or not.

Comment: I just ran into a question where the person explained what they wanted to do and then said "Please point me to examples...I can't find any."  The didn't show any of their own work.  I guess I would classify it as Needs Author Edit because the question seems too broad to me, but it's a slightly different case than "Can you do my homework for me."  Would that be the right response?

Comment: There are a significant number of posts in this queue that I would mark as "Needs author edit". When I select this option, the Submit button does nothing, so I either need to use one of my Flags to indicate the post needs work, or just Skip it. Is this a bug, or is there a condition I'm not satisfying? Voting and leaving comments on the post do not cause the Submit button to work for me in this case.

Comment: *"Use **Needs Community Edit** only for  **complete and on-topic** questions which simply require a cleanup."* - What if I *can't* determine whether the question is *complete and on-topic* **before** a community edit? Most of the questions posted by newcomers are written in broken English, with poor indentation/code formatting, so I sometimes feel like an archaeologist/code-breaker!