# Increasing triage "Should be improved" detail and use that for self-improvement of new OPs

Tags: discussion, triage, help-improvement

There have been questions on improving the triage queue, on getting new OPs more involved and other related issues. In the following I like to start a discussion that involves an integral approach of improvement based on new circumstances created by the Triage queue and the fact that it is almost always empty.

The following is based on my subjective impression of having done a few of the reviews in the Help and Improvement queue and in the Triage queue. I am more and more getting the impression that time spent in H&I improves the questions, but doesn't really help the OP to improve their asking capabilities. 
The feedback you can give in a comment field is limited and you can only hope that the OP does something with it on the next question asked. IMO this is too late, such feedback could help the OP to improve their own question.

There are a few steps we can take, and the question is whether we should take them, which combined with some assumptions that need to be, or prove to be true, that can lead to new OPs improving their own questions. Feedback on perceived feasibility and correctness of assumptions is what I am seeking here so this might lead to a feature request.

**Assumption 0**: Triage "Should be improved" is extended with sub selection of "reasons" and this does not negatively impact the number of open items in the queue (currently often zero). That info can directly be used to inform the H&I editors, in a similar way that was proposed by Nathan Tuggy in [Allow special comments to be passed to H&I queue from Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294880/1307905), but later should be fed back directly to the OP.

The multiple selectable items should include:

- remove fluff (thanks, hi, name, Can anyone help me ... please), repetition
- add a sentence with a question mark e.g. by transforming a "I want" statement
- use a spell checker in to correct spelling
- correct punctuation (no spaces before/after)
- read about formatting code correctly
- follow English capitalisation rules

(the above cover 99.5% of all H&I improvements that can be made).

**Assumption 1**:
A subset of the OPs can be defined selected as "new OPs" on, e.g., a combination of these features:

- never asked a question before
- reputation below a certain threshold
- previous question edited /down-voted/triaged as needing improvement.

So assuming an OP is selected and their new question is selected directly on submission to be triaged:

**Assumption 2**: Questions by new OPs are selected in real-time to be inserted in the Triage queue

**Assumption 3**: The triage queue, including improvement in assumption 0, is empty often enough that we can predict the Triage for a new question to be under X minutes. If this X is low enough (e.g. 5 minutes) the OP is notified to hang around **as their question might not be posted on the site based on the result of the triage when it needs improvement**. A delay of an hours/days or more for feedback as you now get via the Close queue (if at all) is not motivating an OP to improve the post.

**Assumption 4**: Extended Triage feedback is consistent enough (according to some criteria) to give specific feedback to the new OP with instruction what to do to improve the question and make it acceptable to be posted. Posts updated by the OP will be re-triaged. The new OP should be made very clear that for their post to be a acceptable to the site at this given time requires conformation to some minimal standards.

**Assumption 5**: Some way for a new OP to ask for assistance about making the question acceptable is implemented. They should be prevented from asking about the subject of their post. The points of improvement could be listed (with would have links to detailed examples for each) and the OP should be to select one or more of these and hit a button with "I need help with these improvements". Feedback on those issues, from helpers, should not consist of doing the changes, but should only be n the form of  writing comments like "Remove the last two lines with thanks and your name, they are chit-chat and don't belong here". ( *I much rather help OPs that way by forcing them to learn by doing, than making the actual changes for them.* ).

If the OP is not interested in hanging around for feedback the question will not be posted if not getting through Triage. Or not interested in making the post conform to minimum standards, it will not get placed on the site.

The above could be implemented in a step by step way, providing gradual improvement and allowing confirmation of assumptions made about. If at some point e.g the Triage queue builds up, then posts by new OPs could directly go to the site (as they are now).

If all the assumptions hold I think implementing these steps could lead to decline of low quality questions. That might result in the H&I queue being more interesting.

Is the above a good direction? Is there evidence that the assumptions won't hold, so none of this makes sense? Should we ask for concrete feature requests working towards such a goal?

Comment: The request in your Assumption 0 has been made previously: [Allow special comments to be passed to H&I queue from Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294880/allow-special-comments-to-be-passed-to-hi-queue-from-triage).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: Yeah, although I suggested a somewhat different set of predefined options. Perhaps Anthon can suggest his as another answer and we can work out the pros and cons of each there ;)

Comment: The second half of Assumption 3 might not follow on smaller sites.

Comment: @o11c Are there other sites where Triage is done?

Comment: @Anthon uh ... I always assumed so, but I don't have review privileges anywhere else except https://unix.stackexchange.com and that doesn't show one.

Comment: @o11c I have those rights on [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/review) and [Ebooks](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/review) and there is no Triage there. Nor on others I have looked. You don't need the right and can circumvent not having the link for review by just creating it yourself: `http://sitedomain/review` (you can't vote though)

Comment: Add to assumption 0: "This needs/isn't a MCVE."

Comment: @Teepeemm That could be included, but during current triage those should be triaged as Unsalvageable shouldn't they.

Comment: @Anthon Unsalvageable-> and the which concrete sub-reason? 
Also: I think there is a very strong point in Assumtion 0.

Comment: @Xan-KunClark-Davis I am sorry for your so downvoted posts, you clearly don't get from the site what you would deserve. However, remaining here and representing the supressed, minority opinions helps a lot the site. Don't give it up! The site needs us. :-)

Comment: @peterh Thanks for the kind words. Much appreciated. My other question was actually more about the long term-effects and sort of game-theory thinking - and totally not about imaginary points :-) Coowl shades, btw...