# Request for additional confirmation if reviewer picks Requires Editing at question with many votes down and close

Tags: feature-request, triage, review-suspension, question-quality, a-b-testing

Suggest to perform [a-b-testing](/questions/tagged/a-b-testing) of a feature such that when Triage reviewer picks Requires Editing on a question with multiple votes down and close (say 3-4) system would show them additional popup before completing review.

Popup should remind user that option they picked is intended only for questions that can be brought to good shape by someone else than asker. In particular, it would be helpful to explicitly point that editing to get code [from external link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/839601) or to recover it [from image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500/839601) is a job only for asker, not for other users.

Popup should provide user two options: first is to return to reviewing the question (selected by default) and second is to confirm the Requires Editing decision and complete review.

<sup>Alternatively or additionally ([borrowing idea from Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363221/triage-requires-editing-notification-to-new-reviewers?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment561683_363230)), popup could require reviewer to enter their explanation of what kind editing is needed: *please leave a comment for potential editors. This post could use some editing to fix... [ ]*</sup>

Make it possible for moderators to check whether this popup was shown to reviewer and how it was handled. I ask for this because I expect this to help moderators decide whether to suspend a reviewer who incorrectly picked Requires Editing.

---

Related:

- [Triage "Requires Editing" description is (still) misleading](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366334/839601)
- [Triage "Requires Editing" Notification to New Reviewers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363221/839601)
  <sub>This request even proposes a sketch popup that can be used here (I would prefer user actions suggested here but that's not critically important). Criteria and purpose of showing the popup are substantially different though. Readers interested in more detailed discussion of the differences can find it after the list of related posts.</sub>
- [Triage queue - Requires Editing vs. Too Broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356430/839601)
- [Review Triage - What should I do if the question requires information from the OP?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351593/839601)
- [Replace "Requires Editing" button text with "Needs help"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346194/839601)
- [Adopt a consistent policy on what "Requires Editing" means in the review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332546/839601)
- [Fixing the disconnect between VLQ and Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323945/839601)
- [Change triage guidelines for "requires editing"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321895/839601)
- [Triage Review - Questions that require editing from the author](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320174/839601)
- [Triage Review Queue - Inconsistent guidelines for "Requires Editing"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319128/839601)
- [Are reviewers affected when a number of posts they send to H & I go back to Triage?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297635/839601)
- [Increasing triage "Should be improved" detail and use that for self-improvement of new OPs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297389/839601)
- [Help and Improvement review queue not working](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291562/839601)
- [Suggestion for rewording of triage review guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289738/839601)
- [Rephrase Triage help text for "Should be improved" and "Unsalvageable "](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288779/839601)
- [Difference between Should Be Improved and Unsalvageable in Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287024/839601)
- [Triage: How to vote if more information is needed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278735/839601)

---

As promised above, here is a complementary discussion comparing details of this request and [Triage "Requires Editing" Notification to New Reviewers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363221/839601)

A difference that probably springs to mind first is that this request suggests showing a popup only when already existing votes down and close provide solid indication that reviewer would better think twice before picking Requires Editing.

A less noticeable but probably most important difference is that popup proposed here has a wider purpose in that it aims to help not only reviewers but also moderators involved in handling troublesome triage decisions. This naturally follows from the difference in criteria for showing the popup which picks questions where Requires Editing is quite likely a wrong way and might be of interest for moderators because of that (as opposed to totally random picking of reviews in other request).

Third difference follows from purpose of helping moderators to handle troublesome reviews and it is that there is no limit of popups shown to reviewer, no matter how many reviews they handled in the past. This is important because it spares mods from having to count and guess, like "oh this user is long past the limit of showing popup and last time they have seen it was long ago so maybe they just forgot the guidance and made an honest mistake".

I think it is very important for moderators to have clear unambiguous context when deciding how to handle particular troublesome review.

---

<sub>PS. I wrote in comments that references to related posts work better than my own examples but this one is really tempting to show: the question has been triaged twice ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/19017323), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/19017659)) and every time all three (total six!) reviewers picked Requires Editing. Full question text is: *"Need SQL query one is dependent on second and second on third table and all attributes are string values <[screen shot of handwritten(!) tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I0Zq.jpg)>"* (title of the question is the same as text). Requires editing, yeah sure. However wrong their decision feels, I honestly can't blame reviewers because it looks like none of them ever had a chance to better learn about what it really means.</sub>

Comment: when drafting this request I prepared a list of example posts showing where I think suggested feature would be useful (to prevent reviewers from making wrong decision). But closer study of discussions listed in _Related_ section made me feel that referring these would do a better job in that

Comment: Your definition of "required  editing" is consistent of the wording used in the review queue itself, where it says that edits by the author can solve the issues in the post

Comment: @Ferrybig which is what close votes are indication of. If there are close votes indicating that only the author can solve the issues with the post, reviewers selecting "requires editing" have to be corrected. Now the actual issue I see with this is that the triage was supposed to be a fast queue, so users with vote to close need to be faster than the queue itself to trigger this.

Comment: SE has so far refused to so much as change the directions on the review page for how to use that button.  If they've refused to so much as change the text in a label from specifically instructing people to use "requires editing" for posts that only the author could possibly salvage, then I wouldn't exactly expect them to add a popup that fires conditionally with the proper instructions.  It's just expecting more out of SE than they're clearly capable of.

Comment: @Servy to be fair, they did change it from "Should be improved", to what it is now. They just didn't change it to what the community wanted it to be, because as both shog and tim post have said: there was a different vision for what the helper queue was supposed to be. It was supposed to be for more than just edits, a sort of a mentoring queue where reviewers would communicate with the author of the post to suss out the important details and help them bang it into shape. It was just a naive idea that didn't come to fruition, and causes friction with the community's vision for the helper queue.

Comment: @TinyGiant Sure, it was supposed to be that. But they didn't make it that.  So when they changed the HI queue into something other than what they originally designed, they should have changed the guidance along with it.  They still haven't done so, despite it being several years now, and because they didn't, they completely prevented the HI queue from ever having a shot at being useful, and resulted in an enormous amount of bad questions being handled improperly by Triage.  They can still fix it.  It's probably the simplest feature to ever possibly implement, and yet they haven't.

Comment: @Servy i agree, I'm just saying that it's not as simple as they haven't done anything. They just didnt do what the community wants. IIRC tim still thinks it can be that, and shog has recently given up hope, so I do predict a change in the wind, we just have to convince tim.

Comment: @TinyGiant I *do* think it's as simple as that they haven't done anything.  It was more complex than that when only Triage existed, and HI hadn't been created yet, but from the moment they created HI and it had no mechanism for dealing with questions requiring the OP to improve them, they needed to change the guidelines, and simply haven't.  If/when the changed HI to actually support additional types of questions, they could have again changed the guidance of Triage accordingly.  If they change it now it'd be better than nothing, but it's really too late for that lone to fix the problems.

Comment: @MEE apparently not a duplicate (notice how it's listed first in Related section). Suggested feature 1) is not for new reviewers but for all reviewers at all 2) not for some fixed number of first reviews but for all reviews at all and most importantly, 3) popup is shown only in special cases where actions of other users (votes down and close) make strong indication that Requires Editing is unlikely the right choice. (I'll edit this clarification of the difference into post and vote reopen if it gets closed by mistake)

Comment: @gnat ok, agree with your arguments. I would retract my flag but I can't because it has already been marked helpful by others. Hopefully your post is not closed.

Comment: ...forgot to mention another difference that I consider very important: one of the main points of this this feature is to aid moderators in deciding whether to suspend a reviewer or not