# Help tip for "Requires Editing" is incorrect in the Triage review queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, triage

In the Triage review queue, the help tip for "Requires Editing" is incorrect and erroneously uses the word "author".

[image: Requires Editing: for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable.]

Some of this has already been discussed extensively in the following posts:

[Is there a guide for the Triage queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/2657515)
[Allow special comments to be passed to H&I queue from Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294974/2657515)
[Help us test question triage!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278380/2657515)
[Changes to "Requires Editing" button in the triage queue *[+complete string of duplicates]*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357470/2657515)
[Review Triage - What should I do if the question requires information from the OP?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351593/2657515)

Summary of the guiding thoughts for this change:

> Do not choose "Requires Editing" if you know the question cannot be made answerable without clarification or additions from its author. If only the author can fix the question, the correct option is "Unsalvageable".

#### Proposal for the following minor changes to the help tips in the Triage queue:

- Action button text should change from "Requires Editing" to **"OK, but requires Minor Edits"**
- Tool tip for the action button *(a.k.a Title text)* should change from

  - "this question could be good, but requires some time and attention of editors" *to*
  - **"this question could be good, but requires some time and attention from community editors"**
- Help text *(e.g. under the [more] link)* should change from

  - "for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable" *to*
  - **"for questions where edits by community editors would result in a question that is clear and answerable"**

No changes are necessary for any of the other Triage buttons or help text.

*(Thanks to the helpful [robinCTS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1961728/robincts) for encouraging me to pursue some of these thoughts.)*

Comment: Here's [another feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321895/change-triage-guidelines-for-requires-editing?noredirect=1&lq=1) along the same line. I understand that we can't expect to receive an explanation for every feature-request that doesn't get implemented, but this one baffles me by far the most. 1. This issue is brought up all the time. 2. Apparently nobody (at least from the community) disagrees that this is a problem that needs to be fixed. 3. The fix is as easy as changing two strings of text and would take almost no time at all.

Comment: There has to be a specific reason why this doesn't get implemented, but I just can't think of one. Is it a lack of time? Surely, someone could have squeezed this into the tight schedule between [creating a StackOverflow app](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349255/6214222) and [collecting every possible stat about Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/15/thanks-million-jon-skeet/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=hero&utm_campaign=jon-skeet-milestone) at some point during the past two years or so.

Comment: It would be nice to finally hear an official opinion/reasoning as to why this request apparently won't ever be implemented.

Comment: [I'm not, at this point, inclined to discourage sending things to the queue where it's pretty clear that only the author could provide the additional information. Data from this is still extremely noisy, but posts that went to the helper queue and only received a comment tended to do as well or better than posts that got edited in some samples, provided that they actually belonged there and weren't incomprehensible in addition to needing an edit only the author could provide.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302511/4639281) — [Tim Post ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post)

Comment: Just exchanging the button tooltip with its label, like [this](https://i.imgur.com/wnYjSCQ.png), would make the triage system twice as good as it is now.

Comment: @MikaS I like the Triage system as it is, but I also appreciate the short button labels.