# Triage guidance for Requires Editing: "Pull code in from hosting site linked in question", how it is handled in H&I?

Tags: discussion, triage, help-improvement, external-links

[Triage guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/839601) suggests this as a reason to pick Requires Editing:

> Pull code in from hosting site linked in question...

Above guidance is easily available for Triage reviewers because it is directly linked from Triage dialog (some complain that it's [not prominent enough](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351022/839601) but that's rather tangential to my question).

I wonder how are H&I reviewers supposed to know that it is expected of them to pull the code from external links in the questions that were passed from Triage?

---

I checked H&I dialog and could not find any guidance on that matter. I also checked [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294974/839601) which introduced mentioned wording for Requires Editing and couldn't find explanation for this neither in the request nor in its linked / related discussions.

I probably wouldn't worry much if it was some natural, widely accepted approach but it looks like opposite indeed.

Specifically, a [popular close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258685/839601) suggests that way to go in cases like that is voting / flagging to close and not editing:

> must include... code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**

<sup>(emphasize with **bold font** is not mine, it is in original guidance at meta as well as in close dialog)</sup>

As far as I can tell Triage reviewers are instructed to pass to H&I a kind of questions that many (most?) H&I reviewers would consider worthy of closing instead of editing.

Is there a reason to worry and do something about this or have I missed something?

Comment: I don't get it.  H&I is about editing the question into shape.  If the question needs the code added to it to be in shape why shouldn't it go there to be edited?

Comment: We should ***almost never** copy code from off-site locations into posts here*. Doing so re-publishes the code under CC BY-SA 3.0. Doing so inappropriately is a copyright violation. It's rare for a site to have a license which makes copying acceptable. Even when it could be acceptable, most people don't include appropriate attribution, which makes those instances of copying also copyright violations. Unless you are familiar with the legalities and license for the source site, you **should not copy off-site code into posts**.

Comment: @NathanOliver my concern is I think about how H&I reviewers are supposed to know that they are expected to do the edit while elsewhere they are taught to close instead - and there is nowhere to learn that it's different in this queue (I checked the H&I UI, it really has nothing about that). Essentially, even though you want them to edit, they are taught that they need to close instead. Kind of broken communication

Comment: @gnat Yes, it's broken. It's been broken for years. There's lots of Meta posts with feature requests/bugs reports that ask for various solutions to fixing this, or at least improving it. Some of those are just trivial edits to the text displayed to reviewers. So far, SE has done nothing, over a period of years.

Comment: Isn't it implicit in the in queue guidence?  *Edit if you understand this question well enough to give it clear, attractive language and formatting
Skip if you don't feel there's anything you can do to help this question or its author*  Seems to me that if you can see it is missing code and the OP provided a link to it then should edit it in.

Comment: As to my previous statement regarding editing in code: please see [Edits that add OP's code from 3rd party site where the license is unavailable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348698) and [Pasting Fiddle snippet into original question as an edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344484)

Comment: @NathanOliver as I said I tried H&I reviews myself to check if maybe this is the case and no, it didn't work. My case was maybe because I am used to close external-link questions but I'm afraid that many other reviewers share that habit

Comment: @Makyen you might be interested in my recent cry for help on these matters, [Request for additional confirmation if reviewer picks Requires Editing at question with many votes down and close](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363939/839601) (it will likely be ignored just like everything else and be just another example of SE team negligence of this problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit made to Triage guidance ([Rev 25](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/295674/revisions)) suggests that this issue has been resolved by removal of *pull-code-in* bullet. This is probably the simplest and least effort consuming approach.

---

For the sake of completeness, another option to address this would be to somehow instruct H&I reviewers that they are expected to pull the code from external link (after verifying that it meets licensing and [mcve](/questions/tagged/mcve) requirements).

And no matter what, it would be helpful to get some stats about how well are these matters handled in review queues, do Triage reviewers tend to correctly identify salvageable questions and do H&I reviewers properly handle such questions that were passed from Triage. This would help us better understand which way to go would be preferable.