# Help and Improvement queue is confusing and half the questions don't need editing

Tags: discussion, help-improvement

Many questions don't require "editing" as such, but more information (code, errors, etc.) or clarification. I can leave a comment and "skip" this review task, but I did what was needed: leave a comment detailing the problems in the post that *only* the author can fix.

Some recent examples I encountered are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/11559245), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/11559017), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/11529176), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/11529175).

I can't fix these questions by editing them. I can leave a comment, and I can edit it for the sake of "completing" the review task, but that doesn't make it an answerable question. It will just bump it up to the top of the "recently active" and possibly the front page. Little to nothing can be gained from editing these question.

Some others actually look fine (
like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/11532671)). What do I do then? Click "Skip?" Will someone else now have to "review" this question that's fine? I'm not "skipping" it, I'm "this post looks fine and doesn't require editing at all"-ing it.

Furthermore, it is unclear to me what the "Question is very low quality" does. I uses this a few times for questions that should be put on hold: Debugging questions without code, unclear what's being asked, etc. But this shows up as "flags" in my profile, all of which have been denied. This is surprising behaviour to me. It also "Skips" the review task; sometimes you want to edit it (e.g. format code) *and* put it on hold as "Unclear what you're asking". That's not "skipping it", that's doing what's needed to (hopefully) get this question in an answerable state.

Part of the problem is perhaps that in the Triage queue there is some ambiguity about what "Requires Editing " exactly means. The intended meaning is "Requires editing from an experienced Stack Overflow user" (I think), but it could *also* be read as "Requires editing from the author". This is *not* necessarily the same!

---

Concretely, some suggestions might be:

- Clarify what "flag as low quality" does example, and/or allow people to put questions "on hold" from the queue.
- Adding a comment on its own should be enough to complete a review task. The queue is named "Help and Improvement". Why assume that "Editing" is the only way to offer said "Help and Improvement"?
- Clarify what to do when a question looks okay.
- Perhaps clarify what "Requires Editing" means in the Triage queue.

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess only 20k+ users get a delete button. Nevermind then. Agreed wholeheartedly that the actions available in the review queues are unclear.

Comment: related: [What's the point of the “Very low quality” flag action, in “Help and Improvement” reviews? Where's the downvote / close option?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300131/whats-the-point-of-the-very-low-quality-flag-action-in-help-and-improvement)

Comment: @gnat It's disappointing that someone independently describes the same problems almost a year later. Especially when the fix seems fairly easy...

Comment: I think there was an explanation for why they keep it that way in one of [meta-tag:help-improvement] questions over here. I don't remember details but back then when I read it it didn't look compelling