# Help and Improvement review queue difficult to use?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Can someone tell me how to work with the Help and Improvement review queue? I just tried it and I failed. I found a lot of the following types of entries:

**Posts I could not improve since they are out of my technical scope** (e.g. a technology I do not know)

There is a skip button. Fine. And there are filters. But it is annoying that I need to type in filters manually. Why can't I use my Favorite Tags for filtering by a single click?

**Posts that could be improved by the author itself** (e.g. missing information)

There is no button for that situation. I can't downvote there. Also the "very low quality" link (that should be a button) is not suited many times.

**Posts that have already been edited by someone else and look fine now**

There is no button for that situation.

**Posts that look fine anyway**

There is no button for that situation.

Is it just me or is there something wrong with that queue?

Comment: Some problems you run into are caused upstream by reviewers in the Triage queue making the wrong call: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291645/578411

Comment: As for your second point, *Posts that could be improved by the author itself (e.g. missing information)*, more people [have complained](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294318/please-rename-the-should-be-improved-button?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Help & Improvement queue could use some improvements itself.

It is fed from the Triage queue; posts that are marked "Requires Editing" in Triage are shunted into the Help & Improvement queue.
However, Triage review itself has been subject of debate. Its users have the options <kbd>Requires Editing</kbd>, <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> and <kbd>Skip</kbd>.
It is the <kbd>Requires Editing</kbd> that causes confusion; some posts can only be improved by the original asker. Triage reviewers tend to click <kbd>Requires Editing</kbd> on these, sending it to Help & Improvement. When it can only be improved by the asker, it should be put on hold - <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd>. I guess some Triage reviewers also find it harsh to call a new user's post "Unsalvageable". So the names of these buttons are misleading.

On to your points:

> Posts I could not improve since they are out of my technical scope (e.g. a technology I do not know)

This is going to happen in any queue. As you pointed out, you can just <kbd>Skip</kbd> these.
But note that techhnical scope is not the only thing here. The purpose of the queue is to show new users how the site works, and improve their question - not to answer it.

> Posts that could be improved by the author itself (e.g. missing information)

These should have been put On Hold, not sent to the Help & Improvement queue.

> Also the "very low quality" link (that should be a button) is not suited many times.

True. I avoid that button, even when it is Low Quality some sloppy reviewers in other queues are going to get my flag disputed or rejected.

> Posts that have already been edited by someone else and look fine now

The queue is not only about editing, but also about teaching. (This is my pet peeve about the queue - most reviewers there only make small edits and don't explain anything about how the site works).
If a new user needs explanation, provide it! Comment, comment, comment! The queue is there to help new users, so teach them - be the one who guides them in the confusing world of Stack Overflow! (And yes, for new users, all of our rules can be *very* confusing - don't be mistaken about that!)
If the site forces you to edit before you can comment, then... oh well, make that minor edit, since you have full edit privileges anyway. I'm not in favor of minor and pointless edits, but if that's what it takes to ease a new user in.... it's a small price to pay.

> Posts that look fine anyway

Again, should not have been sent into H&I. Still, if it's from a new user, there might be something they need to know.

So - the queue itself could use improvements. But you can still make yourself useful there. Plenty of new users who could use a friendly voice and a guiding hand.