# Add close option to the "Help and Improvement" queue to avoid cluttering flags?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, vote-to-close, help-improvement

There are some [good questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291741/is-the-help-and-improvement-queue-just-bad-question-purgatory) on meta about the Help and Improvement queue.

**Can we have the option to vote to close questions in the Help and Improvement queue?**

Some required editing is based on the author's context, that the reviewer won't have access to. If the question is beyond hope, the actions open to me in the Help and Improvement queue are:

1. Skip - this just wastes my time and any other reviewer to follow
2. Flag as low quality - this just wastes a moderator's time (presumably it's a mod, since that's where other flags go)
3. Navigate to the question in the link and vote to close it - this leaves it in the queue and wastes another reviewer's time until it's closed in the biggest review queue of all.

Based on [Tim Post's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291757/117507), these decaying questions will age out of the queue in time, but since reviewers are conditioned to get the queues down to zero, someone is going to action it before it gets to that.

Can we have a button to close it or explicitly put it back into triage to be closed. If it makes it back into triage, can the question be marked as returned from Help and Improvement so that reviewers know it's a very unhealthy question and to really consider anything other than Unsalvageable?

Comment: How would this be less work for anyone else?

Comment: @shog9 Does flagging a question very low quality move it out of the H&I queue? The longer it remains in the queue being looked at, shrugged at and skipped, the more reviewers time it wastes. If it can't be improved and should be closed, it should be marked as such and moved out of the queue.

Comment: From [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue), commenting on questions that need author's context removes them from the queue, is that the case with the flag too? Does the flag send them for mod attention?

Comment: I know that I tend to avoid the H&I queue because pretty much every question is either impossible without the author's help, or already good enough that it doesn't need editing.

Comment: _"Flag as low quality - this just wastes a moderator's time (presumably it's a mod, since that's where other flags go)"_ No. A VLQ flag sends a question to triage. If you click the link for it in the H&I queue, it sends it back to triage for another look. See Shog's very cool flowchart [on his answer here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288385/hiq-very-low-quality-link/288387#288387) for proof of that. (Not all flags go to the mods- Close flags go to the close queue, NAA and VLQ flags go to the LQP queue, VLQ on questions goes to Triage.) Mods can see them, but they aren't mod only.

Comment: @kendra, thanks, that's really clear.

Comment: @Shog9 rather than a close button, would you be happy if we change that from a link to a button on the toolbar to make it a clearer call to action to encourage it? If it then becomes an action that completes a review action for badges, are we able to keep track of an action against a post in a particular queue from a user, to prevent people pinging a question between queues to game reviews?

Comment: If the HI queue is serving a purpose (prompting useful edits), then it should stick to that purpose - adding other tools dilutes the focus of the queue, which has traditionally not worked well in review. If the HI queue isn't serving its intended purpose, then we need to retool it or remove it entirely, not convert it into yet another LQ/Close/Triage queue - we have those already. Currently running various tests to determine which of these options to pursue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @shog9's comment:

"If the HI queue is serving a purpose (prompting useful edits), then it should stick to that purpose - adding other tools dilutes the focus of the queue, which has traditionally not worked well in review. If the HI queue isn't serving its intended purpose, then we need to retool it or remove it entirely, not convert it into yet another LQ/Close/Triage queue - we have those already. Currently running various tests to determine which of these options to pursue"

Answer (score 4):

In my relatively limited experience with the Help and Improvement queue, a significant fraction of the questions there unfortunately do deserve to be put on hold (typically, because they lack information needed to understand or reproduce the problem).  While opening the question in a new tab and voting to close there does work, it's a clumsy workaround at best.

Since I'm already using [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) to [improve the review interface](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172931/please-put-answers-underneath-questions-in-close-review-queue), I figured that it should be possible to add a functional "close" button directly to the review page, letting me cast a close vote without having to open a new tab.  Indeed, it turns out that questions on the review page *already have* a "close" link below them — it's just hidden by default, and the code to open the close vote menu isn't initialized.

In fact, enabling this "close" link only requires the following two lines:

```js
StackExchange.vote_closingAndFlagging.init();
$('.post-menu .close-question-link').show();
```

A bit more work is required to re-run this code every time a new review item is loaded, but fortunately SOUP already provides [a convenient utility method](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/wiki/SOUP-utility-functions#souphookajax-regex-code-delay-) for that.

Anyway, this code is now part of SOUP v1.32, just released today.

Note that, currently, voting to close a question from review does *not* dismiss the review in any way; you'll need to click "Next" (or possibly "question is very low quality") yourself to proceed to the next question.  I think it would be possible to make this happen automatically, but that would take a bit more work.