# Why was this "Very Low Quality" flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts, disputed-flags

I raised a VLQ flag on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53776017/jstl-in-web-application-in-java) question.

It is marked *disputed*. How and why will that ever happen? Is that because the moderator(s) did not agree with it? If so, shouldn't it have been *declined* instead?

Comment: if you check the [question timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53776017/timeline) you'll see two incorrect triage reviews: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21686869), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21687001) where reviewers should be suspended for disregarding what [requires editing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366583/839601) mean. One of these reviews made your flag disputed

Comment: The [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53776017/timeline) does not look great.  At least the first post reviewer didn't do anything about it, perhaps the cause of the dispute.  Two triage reviews are odd, no idea that this was even possible, the way they reviewed it curls everybody's toes.  Review is the site's worst feature.

Comment: @gnat A question goes through more than once in a particular queue?! Since when?

Comment: see the [chart here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288387/839601) - yes the question can go through triage many times. @HansPassant it didn't go through first posts review, no questions go through it anymore. One of the main goals of triage was to drop questions off FP reviews completely since it has proven to be broken beyond recognition

Comment: Why bother flagging? Isn't VtCing easier in these cases?

Comment: @yivi It appeared in the H&IP queue, where I chose to flag it via the link.

Comment: "Disputed" flags [always come from the community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361607/1426539), one way or another. Never from moderatords.

Comment: That's a good piece of info @yivi

Comment: :( That timeline is awful. Triage gone wrong (requires editing on a clearly unsalvageable post), then H&I gone wrong (editing only to inline an image of code but leaving a link and a stray bracket), then triage gone wrong again (back to requires editing). Is there some _3 wrong results from review queue on a single question_ hat I'm not aware of?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth This one will definitely grab a spot!

Comment: You should basically never cast a VLQ flag on a question.  All you're doing is saying, "I think this question should be closed, but I don't know for what reason, someone else figure out the reason that applies and flag it for closure for the real reason".  And that's just not useful.  If you think the question should be closed, (or vote in your case, because you have the close vote privilege, making a VLQ flag even worse as the question isn't getting a needed close vote) for whatever reason applies best.

Comment: Contrary to the previous comment, VLQ is not a flag for closure, [it's a flag for _deletion_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous/93606#93606). It says so right in the description. But I agree that [it is pretty much pointless to cast one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323946/603977).

Comment: @yivi disputed red flags come from moderators.

Comment: @Servy if they are available as an option in the H&IP queue, pretty sure they mean something.

Comment: @CalvT I've been told by a mod otherwise. _Disputed_ from the community, _Declined_ from moderators or community depending on the circumstance. Read the answer by Brad Larson I linked earlier.

Comment: @yivi that answer says "The disputed state comes from a special moderator action that clears spam / offensive flags from a post, and can be applied retroactively even after a flag has been accepted or declined." Look under the spam offensive heading. And I can confirm this as I deal a lot with spam flags.

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's what the flag was *originally* designed to be (and was for a number of years, including at the time that *7 year old* post was made).  It was changed completely in how it's handled once Triage was created, and now only asks people if they want to close the question.  Reviewers of a VLQ flag can't delete the post even if they *wanted* to.

Comment: @Calvt You are right. It's a corner case but I didn't catch it. Still, in this case (VLQ flag), _disputed_ does come from the community. Disputed can only come from a mod in case of a Spam flag.

Comment: @CinCout Yes, it means that the HI queue is completely broken.  That the flag even exists at this point is frankly bad design.  Don't contribute to the problem by using it.  If you think a post should be closed, vote to close it, rather than casting a VLQ flag and hoping that the reviewers will cast a close vote/flag for you, and being upset when they (incorrectly, but unsurprisingly) don't.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297489/add-close-option-to-the-help-and-improvement-queue-to-avoid-cluttering-flags @Servy