# Help and Improvement needs improvement

Tags: feature-request, help-improvement

I spent some minutes clicking through the help and improvement review queue.
I basically skipped all questions. These questions needed improvement, however, the only thing I could do is helping the original author to improve his question.

The main problem was that the author left out a minimal example, forgot to ask a question,....

Bottom line is: quite often it is clear that also no one else could help. Would it be possible to not only skip the question but provide a button back to original author and if that one is clicked by three or more or less reviewers it is removed from that queue.

Comment: It's a well-known problem with H&I. Here's a similar feature quest to add close/flag options to the queue. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291741

Answer (score 12):

In cases like this the question should just be closed. Visit the question directly and vote or flag for closure, then go back to the review queue and skip the review. This puts the question into the close vote review queue where it belongs. If a question becomes closed, it will no longer be reviewable in the help and improvement review queue.

It might make sense to have an option such as <kbd>Nothing to do here</kbd> that marks the review task as completed if x number of users select it, but you might be wrong, and someone else might be able to make it on-topic or it might not even be off-topic. I've seen plenty of users certain that a question is off-topic when it simply isn't.

Basically, unless a question is closed or edited, I don't think it should be removed from the help and improvement review queue.

---

<sub>You could flag it as VLQ and pass it back to triage where it will very likely be reviewed incorrectly again and either pushed to the front page or back into the help and improvement queue; but if the question no longer fits the criteria for entry into triage, it will be pushed into a moderator queue where you will likely get a declined flag. All of this would be an exercise in futility and is likely to either get you a flag ban, or drive you bonkers.</sub>

Comment: I have a vague memory that Skip actually acts like Nothing To Do Here, but I'm not sure this is correct, and the source is probably some random Shog9 comment two years old.

Comment: "...either get you a flag ban, or drive you bonkers." http://i.imgur.com/s4eamxv.jpg

Comment: If most H&I questions deserve closure, this approach effectively turns H&I into a crap, awkward version of the CV queue. That doesn't seem like a good use of reviewer time. I'm not saying there's a *better* way to use the H&I queue - using VLQ flags to push stuff out of it is the by-design flow for handling these cases shown in the Triage/H&I flow chart, but as you point out the moderator tooling around that flow is broken and doing things the intended way will inevitably cause a flag ban. The only sensible solution is not to use these broken queues at all.

Comment: @Mark Sure, if you expect everything to be perfect then the only sensible solution would be to not review. If you care about the quality of content on this site and understand that perfection is unattainable, then the sensible option is to do the best you have with what you have. It ain't perfect, but what in this world is?

Comment: And to step back a minute, why do you want to put stuff back into triage if you already know where it needs to go? You've already effectively triaged it when you decided that it can't be fixed through edits from the community. It is a truly pointless endeavor to send a post that was improperly triaged back to the triage queue that improperly triaged it in the first place, after you have already properly triaged it.