# Why is there no "other action" for help / improvement?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

I just came across some [question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/16169510) in the Review "Help and Improvement" queue.

And as so often on that queue, I saw **no point** in editing this question. The only reasonable thing I saw: close it out for being too broad.

It feels like every time I visit this queue, I find mostly such things! I can look and skip at 5 or 10 or more questions; to find one that maybe could be edited. For all the others, the "action" to take would rather be closing it out, or at least asking the OP for more information.

Thus: at least for me, that review queue needs another button, like: "Edit not possible", or "other action taken", whatever. So that the system could be notified that this thing can **not** be edited.

You see: there must have been people putting up that question for "edit". And they failed. Miserably. When potential editors can only skip such questions, the system has no chance to determine that people disagree with the former "can be edited" assessment.

I get it: this queue wants to push people to spend time to **edit** newbie input. But at least for me, the whole setup is so frustrating and not at all motivating ... that I rather look around myself for things to edit; instead of looking into that queue.

(bonus question: are there any statistics how often questions get edited and end up being well received? I am simply wondering if that queue, and all the work spend to triage for questions that need editing ... leads to some reasonable "return on investment")

Comment: There *is* a VLQ link in the right-hand sidebar, which flags the question to send it back to Triage whence it came. This is of dubious effectiveness, though, since Triage may well get it wrong again, and some questions aren't VLQ enough to really qualify despite there being no useful editing to do.

Comment: [2 looks ok, 2 ussalvageable, 3 requires editing...](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/16145784) we need a advantage scoring system, like tennis.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I tried that link once on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42023499/4284627) and it automatically flagged the post as VLQ. Later, my flag got declined and the question was closed as Unclear what you're asking. Since then, I never use that link and instead skip the review and open the question in a new tab and flag it as Should be closed. I agree with this feature request that a "flag" or "vote to close" button in Help and Improvement would be useful.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I am aware of VLQ. But The point is: in other queues, I can tell the system that I decided on "taking other action". I know that I can flag the posting, or jump to a question and put in a close request. I am complaining that this queue doesn't allow me somehow "indicate" that I did more than just "skipping".

Comment: @NathanTuggy indeed - posts that merely require closure aren't VLQ, and making it a policy to flag them as such whenever you see them in H&I just means (if I understand the flows correctly) bothering a moderator over the majority of the H&I posts you review. That's clearly not helpful. The only sensible thing to do is not touch these broken queues and wait for staff to give us non-harmful actions we can take besides skipping the majority of items.

Comment: @Braiam And if 6 votes are reached without a final verdict, mod-flag since the community obviously can't handle it.

Comment: A recommend closure button would be nice.  If it gets x of those then it is removed from the HIQ and placed into the CVQ.

Comment: @Siguza that has the potential of becoming too much noise for the moderators. Remember, moderators are exception handlers.

Comment: @Braiam I thought this might be the case, but... we can't query SEDE on that, can we? Also, I would argue that such an event is a case where the community might have been able to handle something, but has failed to do so... similar to when a post is locked due to edit wars.

Comment: A lot of times I find that the problem is that the question is missing code. It is sort of hard to edit the question and add the missing code when I'm not the one who wrote the code. Those questions need to be closed, not edited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the "Help and Improvement" queue just bad-question purgatory?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291741/is-the-help-and-improvement-queue-just-bad-question-purgatory) and [Help and Improvement needs improvement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346052/help-and-improvement-needs-improvement?rq=1)