# "Question of low quality" link in help and improvement review queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts, help-improvement

There is a "question is of very low quality" link on the right of the "Help and Improvement" review queue.

Why is it there, and not with the buttons (edit/skip) ?

When I am in a review queue, and I'm not sure of the action, I often open the help section to help me decide.
But since this button's action is not in the help section of the queue, I'm not sure when I should click it. Sometimes it's obvious I should click it, but not always.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a review action, so it doesn't count toward the queue limit. This is both good and bad; on the one hand, you can take care of more in a day (assuming you can manage more!), but on the other, of course, it doesn't count toward those precious precious badges.

You use this link whenever a question really needs to go back to Triage because no one in H&I can fix it. (Technically this is also true if it's already fine, although that's kind of a weird corner case and not something to rely on much.)

I'm not sure anyone knows exactly *why* it's not a review action, but I assume it has something to do with the fact that it kicks stuff back to the originating queue.

Comment: In any case, couldn't there be some kind of help for this action ?

Comment: @cosmo0: Sure, but there's not all that much more to say.

Comment: The help pops up in the form of a confirmation dialog when you click it, @cosmo0. Note that while Nathan describes the typical behavior here, that is (always) subject to change - you should do as the link suggests, and use it upon encountering a question that is of **very** low quality.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't just move it back to triage, but actually flags it as VLQ.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Of course. What do you think happens when a question is flagged as VLQ? (It goes into Triage.)

Comment: I mean, yes, I understand that that's how it works and I've seen [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288385/hiq-very-low-quality-link/288387#288387) - but intuitively, when I flag something as VLQ, I'd think it'd go into the VLQ queue.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Point is, this is not behavior that's dependent on H&I. *All* questions flagged VLQ will go into Triage on SO, or else nowhere. No question will ever be put into LQP except as an audit. So I feel comfortable describing only the end state that's a natural result of general processes that are documented elsewhere.