# Where do the Posts in Triage Section of the Reviews come from?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

It is clear where the "First Posts" Review queue comes from: "first posts from new users ", it is written underneath.

Similarly, the Late Answers queue is "late answers from new users", answers which are posted much later than the question by users with low reputation.

But where do the posts of the "Triage" queue come from? Underneath it is only written "Help identify the quality of questions ". This doesn't provide any information on how the post got into the Triage queue in the first place.

There is this question which gives background for the Triage queue: [Help us test question triage!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage)
But it isn't clear on the origin of the questions in the queue. According to the diagram they are new questions which don't have a high enough "Q-score".

What is then a "Q-score" and what is the threshold?

Comment: Q-score is question score (total number of votes, tallied). I don't think the threshold will be known to the public

Comment: After how much time is the Q-score evaluated against the treshold to determine whether it goes to triage?

Comment: again, I don't think this will be known to the public. A lot of the internal workings of the system are not known. people end up figuring out parts of them because they see the end behavior, but the full internal workings are not revealed

Comment: It might have to do something with VLQ flags applied on questions, downvotes, and other indicators that a question needs to pass the _triage queue_.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There are four triggers which can send a question into Triage review:

1. Content heuristics: length, structure and phrases that correlate strongly with questions that have been poorly received in the past.
2. User heuristics: what the author of the post has done on the site previously.
3. Network heuristics: what other authors from the same network as the author have done on the site recently.
4. Very Low Quality flags.

Each of these are considered fairly weak signals by themselves, and will only send the question into Triage if there is no strong, competing signal that it SHOULDN'T be there: upvotes, high reputation, etc. The purpose of Triage itself is to either amplify or squelch this signal, such that the question can be handled appropriately elsewhere on the site.

Comment: Thanks! What is the same network as the author? Is that based on the IP address?

Comment: Yes, network means ip subnet

Comment: @Shog9: Does VLQ flag send the question to Triage or VLQ queue or both?

Comment: @vhu Triage only, [see this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288387/3717023). There are no questions in the LQ review anymore.  Shog9: since you listed VLQ flags among the "fairly weak signals", this implies they do not always send questions to Triage. This seems to contradict the post I linked, where you said "All questions flagged Very Low Quality now immediately enter Triage".

Comment: @1999 if I read correctly, the VLQ flag sends questions to triage unless there's something that says that it shouldn't go.

Comment: This is slightly complicated for VLQ, since the option *isn't even available* when the trigger would be too weak to do anything, @1999. Even then, there are checks that can kick it out of Triage if, for instance, the score changes later on or it gets locked or something. So yes, technically these do get sent into Triage, but they don't necessarily *stay there* very long.

Comment: Wait, what? Given how difficult it is to get questions closed from ths triage queue because of the bad UI, this makes a, VLQ flag a waste of time.

Comment: I'm coming to the conclusion that the triage queue is a con job by the SE owners to make it hard to close crap questions.

Comment: A handful of people had gotten in the habit of using VLQ flags to essentially let them "double dip" on close reviews, @Raedwald - but that was never the intent: it was always supposed to be used in cases where [no amount of editing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous/93606#93606) would help. The Triage workflow matches fairly accurately the workflow used by moderators to evaluate VLQ flags, which is where most of them ended up being handled until recently.