# Where do the Triage trick questions come from?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298843/where-do-the-posts-in-triage-section-of-the-reviews-come-from) asks, where the Triage questions come from. Out of curiosity, I want to ask where the trick questions that appear in the review queue appear come from. Are those actual questions that have been asked? And if so, who decides that they are going to become those questions?

Comment: They probably come from the oozes of doom, I'm handling all day from outside the queues.