# Should I pay attention to answers when in the Triage review queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

Today, when going through the Triage queue, I noticed a typo in a question and posted a comment to ask the author if the typo was only in the question or if it existed in the actual code as well. As it turns out, the typo was the source of the problem and had already been found by someone else and posted as an answer. The relevant question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56462953/same-connection-file-works-for-1-script-but-not-the-other?noredirect=1#comment99520378_56462953)

I'm wondering if I did something wrong (or rather, imprecise) here. I generally don't look at answers when in the Triage queue since they aren't presented during the review. But should I have noticed this one?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue

Comment: I hope it didn't sound like I was criticizing your comment when I asked if you had seen the accepted answer. I just thought it was an odd comment considering that and I was curious. It didn't occur to me that you were seeing the question in a review queue.

Comment: Part of the problem is that the answer shouldn't really be there. Unfortunately it takes too long to close typo questions sometimes.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Why shouldn't the answer be there? The typo close reason says "...this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers." Given past tense for "resolved", the close reason implies that the question was resolved, so the typo has been pointed out. Granted, it could have been resolved by a comment like Kyle gave (which wasn't an answer), but I can't see anything wrong with somebody answering with an explanation of where the typo is using the answer box. They should just be aware the question (and thus the answer) might get deleted if it won't be helpful to future readers.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I didn't take it poorly. I appreciated the comment. It made me stop and think about why I didn't see it.

Comment: @DavyM I could be mistaken, but I was under the impression we prefer typo questions to be closed rather than answered because answers can interfere with the automatic cleanup of non-useful content. Doesn't an accepted, upvoted answer prevent the question from being deleted automatically? I don't really feel that strongly about it, though. There are a lot worse things than a typo question hanging around.

Comment: @Don'tPanic You are right that the Roomba won't pick it up if the answer has been accepted or has an upvote, as per the "RemoveAbandonedClosed" reason. That's a good point, I can see now why we could want typo questions to get resolved in the comments instead of an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Triage is kind of a tough queue. Often, the OP is the one who would need to edit their post, and so as a reviewer it is difficult to substantively provide the missing context.

With regards to adding a comment...

If you are going to leave a comment asking for clarification or trying to solve some issue you observe, do keep in mind often these posts were not *just* posted, and can be hours if not days old. At this point, visiting the question is probably the best avenue to take.

As far as what enters the queue, Shog has spent a lot of time talking about this. Here are two highlights:

> There are four triggers which can send a question into Triage review:
>
> - Content heuristics: length, structure and phrases that correlate strongly with questions that have been poorly received in the past.
> - User heuristics: what the author of the post has done on the site previously.
> - Network heuristics: what other authors from the same network as the author have done on the site recently.
> - Very Low Quality flags.
>
> <sub>source: [Where do the Posts in Triage Section of the Reviews come from?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298847/1026459)</sub>

[image]
<sub>source: [Help us test question triage!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278380/1026459)</sub>

Comment: This makes sense. I think I assumed Triage was for newly posted questions. I'd appreciate some elaboration on how questions get put into the Triage queue if possible.

Comment: @KyleWillmon - Sure, see some of the edits, and also definitely review some of the existing posts on the triage queue on meta.