# Where some questions go after marked as 'question is very low quality'?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, help-improvement

Sometimes a question, marked as "question is very low quality" in "Help and Improvement" review section, would end up in my "Flags" list (and, I guess, waiting in Triage queue, as I learned from this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288387/5468463)). But sometimes, I don't see anything. Where would it go?

**Update**:
Here a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073942/can-i-get-a-4-bit-divider-circuit-structural-verilog-code) to a question I flagged as 'question is very low quality' and here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/18988769) to the review queue. I still can 'Edit' as it is enabled, but the title says that the question is no more reviewable. The question didn't end up in my 'flag' list. On the other hand, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063355/expected-block-count-of-linear-hashing) one did end up in my 'flag' list.

Comment: Hopefully where it belongs.  Deleted questions are only visible to users with more than 10K rep.

Comment: [This might be helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300659/164200).

Comment: @Taryn: Woah...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Is that a good woah or a bad woah?

Comment: @Taryn: A bit of both! Good woah: that diagram is absolutely superb. Bad woah: blimey the system's complicated innit

Comment: (FWVO "bad"....)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What does that acronym stand for? I can't find it on the google.

Comment: @KodosJohnson: It stands for ["Lightness is very tired and can't type properly any more"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/FSVO) ;)

Comment: @Taryn, the post is really impressive :)

Comment: @Vega You've stated that some questions didn't do what you expected them to do, but you've failed to provide any way for someone to explain what happened in those specific cases. In order to do that, we would need A) a link to the post (minimum), B) what you did, C) what you expected to happen, and D) what you observed. Note that most of the information can be obtained by looking at the [post's timeline](/posts/364044/timeline). However, review queue information is only available in the timeline after the post has left the queue, which could take days, particularly for the Close Vote queue.

Answer (score 2):

### General explanation: [Question flags, queues, edits, roomba, community♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252048/question-flags-queues-edits-roomba-community-how-does-this-actually-work/300659#300659)

In [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364044/where-some-questions-go-after-marked-as-question-is-very-low-quality#comment561807_364044), Taryn has linked to their excellent explanation of what happens with flags/vote/queues in: [Question flags, queues, edits, roomba, community♦, how does this actually work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252048/question-flags-queues-edits-roomba-community-how-does-this-actually-work/300659#300659)

### The questions you specifically asked about:

You have not provided the exact times at which you cast VLQ flags, so there's no way to relate your flags to what happened on either question, other than guessing.

For specific questions, you can obtain quite a bit of information from the question timeline. Personally, I use the [SE Modifications](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a) userscript to add a timeline link to questions and answers.

#### The [first question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/49073942) which you flagged VLQ

The [timeline](//stackoverflow.com/posts/49073942/timeline) shows that it did go into:

- [First posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18986893): It entered the first posts queue 20s after being posted and was reviewed. Records for this queue never tell us what happened in the queue, only that it was reviewed.
- [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18986859): Immediately upon posting it was automatically placed in Triage (presumably due to scoring under the required Q score) with the results:

  ```
      Requires Editing × 3, Unsalvageable × 2
  ```

  Your VLQ flag did not put it in Triage, but would have made it require an additional "Looks OK" to get out of Triage, if that was the way the reviews were going.
   The results of Triage put it in:

  - [Help and Improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/18988769) The review was invalidated prior to anyone acting upon it (5 minutes after it entered the queue). No information is provided as to what invalidated the review.
  - [Close vote](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/18988774): It was never reviewed; The review was invalidated by the question being closed as a result of votes made from outside the queue.

#### The [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063355/expected-block-count-of-linear-hashing) you asked about

The [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49063355/timeline) shows that it did go into:

- [First posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18980863): It entered the first posts queue about 5 minutes after being posted and was reviewed. Records for this queue never tell us what happened in the queue, only that it was reviewed.
- [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18980837): Immediately upon posting it was automatically placed in Triage (presumably due to scoring under the required Q score) with the results:

  ```
      Requires Editing × 3, Unsalvageable × 1
  ```

  The results of Triage put it in:

  - [Help and Improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/18981377): The review was invalidated prior to anyone acting upon it (9 minutes after it entered the queue). No information is provided as to what invalidated the review.

While still in the Help and Improvement queue the question re-entered:

- [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18981411): Immediately upon posting it was automatically placed in Triage (presumably due to scoring under the required Q score) with the results:

  ```
      Requires Editing × 3, Looks OK × 1, Unsalvageable × 1
  ```

About 4 1/2 minutes after exiting the Triage queue for the second time it entered:

- [Close vote](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/18982182): It was never reviewed; The review was invalidated by the question being closed as a result of votes made from outside the queue.