# Improve the Improvement queue instructions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help-improvement

The vast majority of questions currently in the Help and Improvement queue are clearly written, but lacking in sufficient details. I had to come to Meta to work out what I should do with these questions (skip them). The current instructions are:

> We need your help editing questions to be clear and answerable.
>   (more)

or

> We need your help editing questions to be clear and answerable.
>   (less)
>
> - **Edit** if you understand this question well enough to give it clear, attractive language and formatting
> - **Skip** if you don't feel there's anything you can do to help this question or its author

Can the first line be changed to:

> We need your help editing questions to be clear and answerable. **Skip** if you feel the question should be closed.

Alternative wording suggestions welcome!

Comment: I doubt that the intention of **skip** is to signal the question should be closed. **Skip** exists because you might feel your knowledge about the subject isn't enough to edit/review a post. (I don't have access to the improvement queue, but I figure skip there works the same as in the queues I do have access to)

Comment: _The vast majority of questions currently in the Help and Improvement queue are clearly written [citation needed]._

Comment: I usually navigate to the question, vote to close, then choose skip. That's the best option you have if you don't want a bunch of declined VLQ flags.

Answer (score 3):

You should **not** be pressing the skip button if you have sufficient knowledge to judge the question, and think the question should be closed!

The *question is very low quality* link below the buttons is for that. Then it can actually get closed.

[image]

Still, your request for improved instructions might be justified. Because it might be a good idea to note this link exists in the instructions.

Comment: That's a call to action? I thought it was informational! I already know _all_ the questions in the Improvement queue are very low quality. The UI _really_ needs improving!

Comment: A call to action should start with a verb, like "Edit" or "Skip".

Comment: As far as I understood, that link might cause a question to go [forth and back between Triage and HIQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300659/294055). Wouldn't it make more sense to manually open the question in another tab and properly flag/vote for closure there?

Comment: @honk No, that's too much trouble. The UI should provide all the approved ways of handling it on the same page.

Comment: @CJDennis: I completely agree. But currently the UI doesn't allow it.

Comment: @honk H&I certainly has its troubles (see [“Help and Improvement” is dead, can we please let it die](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359995/7296893), for example). The H&I-Triage infinite loop is one of them. If you leave it sitting around in H&I (which happens when you cast a close vote by going to the question page), it stays there until it either gets edited (and then it has a close flag) or until it gets bounced back to triage. Better just bounce it back to triage immediately (and throw in a close vote if you have the rep).

Comment: Honestly, someone pressing _requires editing_ in triage should be slapped imo. If a question requires editing, go to the question, edit it, and press _looks ok_. In the H&I we need to agree with the person that it indeed requires editing, deduce what he wanted to edit, and then apply that same edit he should have in the first place.

Comment: That button is actually only for flagging stuff as VLQ. Even though it can send stuff to Triage, it can also send stuff to a mod queue, where your flag will be declined if the question is not actually VLQ and just needs to be closed. The advice I got from shog9 a while back was to go to the question to vote to close, then skip. IIRC if the question gets closed it will be removed from the H&I.

Comment: @TinyGiant Are you sure they don't go straight back to triage? I based that comment on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300659/369403), where a VLQ flag from H&I just moves it to triage. I've not yet seen a diagram where there's a possibility for it going in a mod queue, but there are a lot of them lying around.

Comment: @Erik a VLQ flag is just a VLQ flag. Once the post no longer qualifies for Triage, VLQ flags send the post to a mod queue. I've had it happen a lot in the past before I started just navigating to the question, voting to close, then skipping.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I just flagged a few questions as _very low quality_ in the HIQ, but I can't find any flags in my flag summary. Do you know where they went? Can they actually be declined if they don't turn up in the flag summary?

Comment: @honk it has been a while since I flagged a question as VLQ, but after some research [[The very low quality flag\] will only send the question to the queue once. If it's raised again, it will go to the moderators to handle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300659/288751); but the "very low quality" link in the H&I [does something different in the triage queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288387/4639281). Now it [looks like some still *end up* as flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364044/4639281), I'm fairly certain this is because the question was no longer viable for triage.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Thank you for digging through this confusing stuff. So I guess the questions I flagged still made it into Triage again...