# Thoughts on The Loop #2

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I think [The Loop #2](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/22/the-loop-2-understanding-site-satisfaction-summer-2019/?cb=1) is going into a pretty decent direction. According to the survey, the most common complaints about SO are (unsurprisingly):

1. Unwelcoming community
2. Design
3. Artifact quality

Now, the interesting part is of course what the company is going to do about those:

> Your feedback about unwelcoming community and perceptions of
>   overmoderation led us to prioritize two important user-to-user
>   feedback loops: the question closing experience and review queues. We
>   know that getting a question closed or sharing and receiving feedback
>   about a question can be frustrating and confusing to question askers,
>   question closers, and those working hard to curate site content.
>   That’s why we’re changing the question closing experience so that
>   **questions that need improvements are hidden more quickly and question
>   authors are given specific guidance about how their questions can be
>   improved.** We’re also revamping the review queue experience so that
>   it’s easier and more efficient to use.

<sub>(Emphasis mine.)</sub>

I'll give this plan a bunch of  thumbs up.  It's been a while that something actually constructive has been done about the issue instead of instituting variations on loving summers. This appears to be in line with what the community has been screaming about forever. The onus is clearly put on the question *asker*, and that's a good signal from HQ here. Better tools for reviewers are very welcome too.

> Next, we heard your concerns about design loud and clear. [..]
>   We’re also continuing work with the Stacks team to continue rolling
>   out user-friendly design patterns.

If this means some of the cruft that's been accumulating will be cleaned up, I'm all on board with that too.

> Finally, we are taking steps to improve question and answer quality.
>   [..] We want Stack Overflow to remain a source of high quality
>   question and answer pairs, so we’ll soon be starting to explore ways
>   to continue to keep the library of questions fresh and make it a
>   trustworthy part of all developers’ toolkits.

Sounds good to me, though it's too vague at this point. The goals being signalled here certainly seem like the correct ones though. I might actually start holding my breath on this one.

Overall, these all sound like steps in the right direction. Let's see how this'll play out.

Comment: I would urge caution; "*We’re also revamping the review queue experience so that it’s easier and more efficient to use.*" sounds to me like removing tools and functionality rather than *adding* them. But let's wait and see.

Comment: How is SE gonna improve "answer quality" when it's trying to make high rep users go away?, are they gonna pay people for answering?

Comment: In the post, they mentioned that they coded 2,000+ answers, but didn't say how they chose those answers or the total they received. Given the current state of distrust between the community and SO the company, I'm worried that they could have chosen answers that bolster their agenda.

Comment: @gusmally Even if so, those top three points they picked do seem like top concerns, and their plans on mitigating them seem entirely reasonable, judging from the 30000ft overview they gave. It may still turn out to be a load of betrayal, but I find second guessing everything too exhausting.

Comment: This type of post is best suited for a blog. You should phrase this as an actual question which is set up in a way that supports community feedback for discussion, and post this as an answer.

Comment: @deceze I appreciate your optimism! Hiding questions that need improvement does sound promising

Comment: Yes, it seems they have finally come to their senses, instead of rage wiping everything.

Comment: @PeterMortensen don't hold your breath: this was already tried and failed, see [Triage implementation has been (silently) abandoned midway, how bad is that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374881/839601): "we've been unable to adjust the system..."

Comment: I'd potentially be worried about "as well as reduced complexity of the reputation and privileges system" - there could be a lot of fairly fundamental changes hidden in that sentence (which could be either good or bad changes)

Comment: @David True. I'm not terribly invested in the current system staying *exactly* as it is. If reducing the complexity of it is a net benefit to the site, I'm all for it. Of course, it's also easy to get that wrong, so we'll see…

Comment: "These all sound like steps in the right direction" So did the ask-a-question wizard one year ago, before 2019 summer of love and autumn of meltdown.