# Provide an option to filter the triage queue by tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, review-queues, triage, filtering

I propose to add an option to filter triage questions by tags.

The implementation can be like in the close queue and the motivation for my request is, well, the same as it was when the close queue was [enhanced with filtering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125169/165773):

> I would find it much more interesting to review questions in tags I'm familiar with and can understand the question content of, and it would give me a bit of pride to help maintain "my" section of SO.

I checked about 40 triage reviews I did (or more precisely, skipped) a while ago when I studied something else about triage. Their average time to complete was well over one day - not quite fast - and only 3 of these reviews took less than 8 hours (and of these 3, one seemed to be simply invalidated by a quick question deletion).

If we could attract more reviewers of those who currently abstain because they want to focus solely on maintaining "their" tags, this would lead to faster review completion.

Alternative approach [proposed below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410977/839601) would also be acceptable way out. Can't tell if allowing parallel close review would directly benefit Triage (I think less than adding an option to filter by tags) but it would at least cancel harm currently done by triage to to close reviews.

---

For the sake of completeness, the close queue has yet another way to filter - by close reasons. I abstain from discussing it here, because I haven't yet figured how to match it with the fact that (unlike the close queue) triage can have questions without any flags / votes to close at all.

Also, as a kind of historical note, I think it was the correct design to have no such filter when triage was initially introduced. The thing is, back then it was anticipated to eventually evolve into some extremely efficient solution that wouldn't need any filters. This development was however [abandoned midway](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374881/839601) and as a result I think it is now desirable to use enhancements similar to other review queues that are known to have limited efficiency.

Comment: can't speak for others but to me lack of filters is primary reason of not using this review. I'd like to help with questions in particular tags because per my observations triage algorithms do great job picking troublesome questions, but every time I attempted this it turned out way too cumbersome to "manually filter" the queue to the tags I wanted to review

Comment: Filtering by tag will leave low trafic tag questions outside. While it's OK for the other queues, triage queue needs actions for all questions

Comment: @Vega yes I've been thinking about this when preparing this request. It is in fact the same as in close queue, one can in theory argue that low traffic tags get less attention of close voters because of filtering. Thing is though, this "theoretical" causality doesn't exist in practice: if filtering didn't exist, reviewers who currently use filters would simply not review anything at all. And my experience with triage is exactly like that: with filters I would review *some* questions, without filters I don't review _at all_

Comment: There could be negative filtering by tags (for example, ***exclude*** all questions tagged with Python, PHP, Java, or C#).

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Finally a way to get rid of reviewing [tag:regex] questions :D

Comment: speaking of [alternative approach](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410977/839601) of allowing triaged questions to get to close queue - as a close reviewer, I'd rather prefer to work in Triage _filtered by tags_ - but if making this is not feasible for some reason, then I'd want to hendle triaged questions in close queue (which fortunately can be filtered by tags)

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, we could consider allowing triaged questions to get to close queue.

Thing is, the primary reason why inefficient triage is worrying is in the way how this impacts other reviews - specifically, close review.

It is important to understand that while the question is stuck in triage, system blocks it from getting to other review queues. As a result, we get the situation when system correctly and quickly detects most troublesome questions and then, essentially shields them from getting to close queue - for a full day average, go figure.

This is really *really* weird. The way how things work now, system essentially incentivises askers of poor questions to [pay money for fraudulent release of asking limits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410831/839601). Seeing multiple poor questions hanging open and seemingly unattended for days can only convince them that their ban is mere misfortune and that it makes sense to try their luck again.

(Of course this is not how things were intended to work when triage development started. Triaged questions were supposed to be hidden from everyone except for reviewers so nothing like above would be possible. However this turned out infeasible and as a result we have system working opposite to its original intent.)

---

Given above, one could ask wouldn't it be better to just get rid of triage completely. I considered this and in fact, that would be my next suggestion in case if proposed changes won't help to improve it - because the way how it is now, it really seems to do more harm than good.

Okay, so what good does it do now and why would it be worth giving triage yet another chance to improve instead of just dropping it. My observations on this queue suggest that triage provides a great value of teaching users having under 3K rep. These users can't see close votes on questions - that is, to many of them the whole process of closing may look like obscure and coming out of thin air.

But to triage reviewers, system becomes really transparent. They can learn what questions aren't worth answering and what they should do instead. They learn how to use close flags and how these flags are handled by a system. And those of them who will get to 3K rep will know how to properly use their close votes from day one.

You know, I tried to figure how else people can learn this stuff and nothing I could imagine didn't even come close. The way how system picks inappropriate question for triage and all the mechanics of how this queue works makes it just impossible to beat.

---

Above, I wrote that the way how things work now, we better drop triage completely. I stand by that because I believe that harm of shielding inappropriate questions from close review for *that* long outweighs its teaching value. But I think it would be really a pity if we do this without even attempting to improve.

<sub>Note: above was also submitted as feedback in recent [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369072/165773) at MSE.</sub>

Comment: _"It is important to understand that while the question is stuck in triage, system blocks it from getting to other review queues"_ So if I stumble upon a question that happens to be in the Triage and I VTC, it doesn't actually go into the Close Votes queue?

Comment: @41686d6564 until the triage is over - it abso-friggin-lutely doesn't go to close queue. I tested this myself many times. In fact this could be checked any time viewing any timeline of any triaged question that eventually managed to get to close queue. Close review starts only after traige is completed

Comment: It's worse.. last time I checked, if I flag a post while reviewing, if the outcome is "Looks OK", my flag is disputed. If I recall correctly, that also applies to flags raised outside the queue.