# Don't be that account: buying and selling reputation and bounties

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting-fraud, psa

In recent months we have found several accounts that offered bounties and / or upvotes for hire. You pay them some money, they promise to upvote your content or apply bounties to your questions or for you to earn directly:

> [image: screenshot of an advertisement for a Stack Overflow reputation service, ending in "My price is variable and I can also provide other services such as ..."]

This may sound like an easy way to gain reputation. But, while we encourage everyone to provide great questions and answers and compete for upvotes and reputation, the motivation for doing so needs to be anchored in actually helping the broader community. Stack Exchange works by ensuring that the best information rises to the top, but paying for bounties, upvotes or other services unfairly skews that system, and continuing to do so can result in a lengthy suspension for all involved.

We would hope that the majority of our users already understood that this method of reputation gain is not acceptable here. But, it seems we need to be more explicit about this, so here is our policy, in nice big bold letters:

### Buying or selling reputation, bounties and other favours is a form of voting fraud and not permitted.

The moderation team is committed to battling voting fraud and protecting the integrity of our reputation system. In all recent cases, we have handed out warnings and suspensions, and any reputation gains were reverted, bounties invalidated, and where deemed necessary, posts deleted. **Instead of a profile with a nice pile of reputation, you could end up with a profile with a suspension notice.**

As always, if you know of anyone offering such services, you are welcome to flag a post (theirs or your own) for moderator attention and tell us anything you might know: who is selling, where they are advertising and if you know of anyone having used the service offered.

And if you have, in the past, paid someone for rep gain or have offered rep gain for pay, but want to avoid getting into trouble over it now, consider letting us know directly so we can discuss your specific case. That way you can avoid the sanctions we'd have to apply if we were to find out later through our own investigations.

Comment: also post links to your sockpuppets so we can nuke them

Comment: Jeez, there are people who pay for the services to keep it enough of a market to warrant a PSA? The depths humanity can sink to truly can't be fathomed.

Comment: @OlegValter: this is why we can't have nice things!

Comment: I guess they confused Stock Exchange and Stack Exchange.

Comment: someones was paid to down vote me :D as long as we don't have Gene Rodenberrys Star trek, this is quite normal

Comment: If it can be shared... where are they advertising? and is this SO only or are other sites in the market?

Comment: Oh dear lord, boosters on SE... What's next, gold farmers?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: the most recent case was on Fiverr, but another recent seller had advertised their 'services' by linking to their Fiverr page here on Meta.SO, and I've handled cases on other freelance sites as well. I've not yet seen such services offered for other sites in the SE network, but, I have not exactly been searching for those either.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek If someone bought 15k MSE rep, will they be in trouble? Asking for a friend...

Comment: @Cerbrus gold farmers are already on SE, try a couple of SEDE queries :) I even found half a dozen pornhub merchant (whatever the hell this means) accounts

Comment: Well... For certain values of 'Just how much trouble....' I was thinking more about SU tho

Comment: Sharing some technical details on how did you find these accounts would be great!

Comment: @OfirD that's not going to happen...

Comment: hmm this looks like sort of a proof that [3CV change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391832/839601) works. Just about two years ago such "business" wouldn't be viable because many (most?) of those involved in asking and answering inappropriate questions could keep doing it just fine without paid help. Guess if SE team would additionally [improve Triage efficiency by a notch](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/409089/839601) this market would just soar

Comment: I say we declare this sort of abuse to invoke Undefined Behaviour. Then you can get really nasty. As for PornHub... I remember back in 2005 the folks coming in from head office to investigate several gigabytes of data downloaded from Playboy's servers. Turns out Playboy ran an Eclipse mirror and Eclipse 3.1 had just been released with support for Java 5. Lot of cool stuff in Java 5.

Comment: Various AI and db mining could be used to find such behaviors. Problem is: finding a fruitful newbie and regularly helping him is exactly the same in the processable data, like such a cheat. However, simple sockpuppetry does not really work here. It is too problematic to make it correctly, and doing that, the perpetrator never can sleep very well. Some similar strategy - finding the obvious bad guys by non-disclosed rules - could help also here.

Comment: @OfirD Just speculating, but one could look for accounts that upvote content that others downvote, preferably soon after content creation. Some kind of statistical anomaly detection. Alternatively, they maybe went undercover and offered to do it themselves and when the payment arrived pushed the suspension button instead.

Comment: @Trilarion I don't think it's necessary to speculate about the *how*... this post is more to emphasise that when found (by whatever means) - **it's not going to end up well**  for either the "buyer"/"seller" in such an exchange.

Comment: I assume that the accounts selling the rep are just sockpuppet accounts selling rep generated via sockpuppetry, consequently; any user buying from the user who owns the selling account is bound to wind up very upset, because even if the buyer doesn't get nuked — which I bet `4-out-5` times they do — the seller is bound to wind up nuked at the rate they're going, and all of there votes as I understand it, will go _"bye, bye"._ So the Buyer will end up getting their "paid-for rep" nuked anyhow, which would cost them whatever they were dumb enough to pay. Gawd, how does someone give money away?

Comment: I wonder if this is ever to skip those annoying reputation requirements for commenting etc. Probably more likely for ban/spam-filter evasion, right?

Comment: Warnings for voting fraud?  Does seem strict enough.  If they are offering it to one user how many users have taken them on the offer?  I assume a very deep dive on every vote these users, selling reputation, will happen? The only way anyone will take voting fraud at this kind of serious is if the sellers and buyers are no long welcome at **any community**

Comment: I cannot stop thinking if the two downvoters will be examined more closely :D

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre what's sockpuppets? Is that a website?

Comment: [People offering plenty of bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=416010&tab=reputation&filter=year)

Comment: @aheze A person who creates many accounts for the sole purpose of upvoting posts to gain reputation on a single account. (I.e artificially inflating the reputation that an account has via, fake accounts.)

Comment: I can’t get over that someone linked to their scam **on Meta**. We’re they just trying to see how fast they could get caught?!

Comment: Thos sole surprising thing is that anyone is surprised:(

Comment: I kind of feel like there's no point to this meta post, I don't think this post is going to stop anyone from doing it,  if anything it let's people know that this is an option. I think that a rule under terms and conditions is suffice, most people would assume that this would be a rule violations, and I can't really see anyone trying to argue that this should be more clearly state when it's already in the rules and conditions,

Comment: I tried to check how easy it would be to find these with a SEDE query. Instead I just found [a whole bunch of other spam accounts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1449492).

Comment: @BernhardBarker replacing `reputation` with `services` in your query returns even more spam accounts. Seems the SE network is a good place to advertise your business :)

Comment: There's a significant amount of roofing spam in there... Don't they know all programmers live in someone's basement? The roof is someone else's problem xD

Comment: good job for bringing it to everyone's attention that they can monetize their stack overflow account. I'm sure that won't backfire

Comment: @Sam If it keeps even just one person honest who was considering doing it, it's worth it.

Comment: On the contrary, I hope it encourages people to do it so we can get rid of more bad eggs

Comment: `consider letting us know directly so we can discuss your specific case` letting you know how, exactly? an email? moderator-flag a post? make a meta thread? something else?

Comment: @rdans by that logic, we should hide away every criminal law in the world because knowledge of the existence of a crime leads to said crime being committed. If anything, I think more PSAs like this should be posted to remind everyone that fraud of any kind is not welcome on the network, and that there will be consequences for partaking in such an activity.

Comment: @hanshenrik: your options are: use a mod flag, ping us in a chat room (we'll create a private room), use the contact form to talk to the CM team directly.

Comment: You could setup honeypots that advertise rep-selling. Both inside and outside SE. Definitely in more than one languages.

Comment: @user while an interesting idea, that's called provocation in criminal law and would be judged mistrial in any sane legal system. I think we should adhere to best practices of law here as well - if a law enforcer provokes you to do something, you cannot be blamed for doing so. In any case, the real problem is those who *sell* votes/accounts/reputation, not those who buy - as long as there is supply, there will be a demand. Laziness is part of human nature, after all

Comment: @OlegValter *"the real problem is those who sell votes/accounts/reputation, not those who buy - as long as there is supply, there will be a demand"* - This is flawed logic. One could just as easily argue "As long as there is demand, there will be a supply."

Comment: @OlegValter Indeed provocation should normally lead to mistrial, but it could be done without provoking. Websites can be created that promise such services and with minimal SEO the rep-buyers will click on the first result. Meaning that none of their actions were affected by the honeypot. Also the honeypot can mimic other similar non-honeypot websites.

Comment: @Nick obviously (I am well aware of the Keynesian cross), but it is not those who want to buy are the culprits here. The buyers are just lazy people, whereas the sellers are the greedy bastards (I hope that's not considered against the CoC :)). I fully support cracking down on the latter, but do not think that the buyers are very much to blame.

Comment: I think this can be mitigated using some machine learning to sniff out such activity, given a dataset of examples

Comment: @user well, that iteration indeed does sound better, but I am still skeptical about creating honeypots of any kind because consequence or not, it is still coercion. Whereas raising awareness of the consequences of such buying/selling (because I am pretty sure many [if there really are that many] buyers are not even aware that they are opening themselves to being warned, suspended or worse).

Comment: I'm interested in the motivation here. Are there people who believe that a higher SO rep will be of use when, for example, a person tries to get a job or a contract? I find it difficult to believe that any such employer or contractor would just look at the number without sampling the quality a bit. Some people here have reps which have been boosted by 000s for just asking how to get a substring from a string.

Comment: @mike As one of the reviews for such service said "thanks I can ask questions again"

Comment: @Dharman this kind of hints on how to efficiently detect this kind of fraud (manually or automatically doesn't really matter). If it looks like an asker of some poorly received question has unexpected rep points, a human or automatic system can drill deeper into their prior rep history looking for signs of suspicious upvotes

Comment: @gnat I thought about automating this but scraping this information isn't as easy as it seems. If you can come up with a viable algorithm maybe someone can try to implement it. For the moment manual intervention is required. Even mod tools don't always show conclusive results.

Comment: @Dharman automating this looks more like a job for SE dev team because they have access to voting details. If "service provider" was smart enough to reasonably spread and randomise their upvotes to the client account this would be too difficult to detect neither manually nor automatically without dev-level access to voting details - while having such access would make it a fairly trivial task (and additionally would easily catch other clients of the fraud upvoter account). Another important advantage of dev level access is, it allows to see whether client account was previously blocked

Comment: @gnat LOL. That is wishful thinking. I doubt SE will do any more development on Stack Overflow. Certainly not such a big task. I don't have faith in company making such changes

Comment: @Dharman agree. Guess we can only hope that such a fraud will somehow hurt their commercial interests, then there will be a chance that they allocate resources into addressing it

Comment: "*Improving your questions*" sounds like a legitimate service. And honestly, I would love to see people make use of it!

Comment: I wonder if this could be abused to get someone's account suspended. Though you'd have to be pretty motivated to waste money on that!

Comment: @JAY-DEV: It doesn't get nuked if they have have laundered it through the bounty system. There is no other explanation when a user awards the maximum bounty (500) three times in less than 2 minutes (this information is publicly available). Or awards 50,000 reputation points through bounties over a few weeks or months.

Comment: I’m surprised there is even a market for this. StackOverflow reputation is about as valuable as Reddit karma. But then, there is apparently a market for that too…

Comment: This board clearly needs a reality check.  What is the point of being wealthy if you can't buy anything you want?  Not everyone wants to spend all day answering the same SQL questions.

Comment: @OlegValter "If anything, I think more PSAs like this should be posted.."  I fully support this post but I also think we should not overestimate the impact of it. Very likely only a minority of those targeted will read it. Of course it's still worth it nevertheless.

Comment: @Trilarion oh, yes, I do not think the impact will be significant too, just a nice thing to have that clearly condems the practice and tells passers-by that there are consequences

Comment: hey @PeterMortensen your note of someone spending 50K in bounties made me [suspect myself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165773/gnat?tab=bounties&sort=offered "'Offered bounties for 50,500 reputation'") :)

Comment: @gnat: if you want to tell us something, you know where to find us! :-D

Comment: @Trilarion this post will likely make convenient link to use in respective account suspension notices

Comment: @gnat "this post will likely make convenient link to use in respective account suspension notices" Using it after the crime happened cannot prevent it.

Comment: @OlegValter There will always be people who try to make money from anything they can, and they wouldn't care about any consequences SO can enforce to stop them from doing so (unless they have an SO account they care about). Of course you should make things as difficult as possible (within reason) for sellers, but the only way to really put a dent in this is to crack down hard on buyers as well. I suspect most buyers are motivated specifically by caring about their account. If you take their reputation or suspend or ban them as punishment, that'll be a huge deterrent.

Comment: @Trilarion well if this only saves time and effort relieving mods from repeating detailed explanation of suspension reasons, this would be good enough already. Also this may impact "recidivism rate" by helping first time offenders realise that their suspensions are not because of bad luck but because this kind of fraud is well known and permanently monitored so they would think twice whether it is worth risking their time and money trying to do it again

Comment: @PeterMortensen - _"Ah, okay Peter, good replay. If you don't mind, I am going to ask you to answer the hypothetical example I have created below, because it is something I have been pondering, and cannot get a clear answer for, and It sounds like your the man to ask."

Comment: @Trilarion If you can get PSAs like these to rank high on Google search results for things like "stack overflow reputation selling", I imagine that could have quite a significant impact. Although I don't know for certain how most (or any) buyers actually search for or find sellers.

Comment: _"...worried that she might lose the bounty that was awarded to her."_ So my question is obviously, "What happens..?". Will "Katie-Frank" loose the reputation awarded from the bounty if she deletes the answer that she was awarded the bounty for?_

Comment: @BernhardBarker "stack overflow reputation selling" I think the category is called reputation management in general.

Comment: Why be surprised? Quote Joel Spolsky: "spend a few months earning a five digit Stack Overflow reputation, and you'll be getting job offers in the $100K+ range without an interview" https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/20373 https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/20491

Comment: @4386427 that may have been true 11 years ago, but that's no longer that black and white. Employers do like seeing _what kind of answers_ you write, as evidence of your communication skills and expertise. Of course, if someone is so concerned about how their profile might come across to potential employers, they also need to weigh what effect having their account suspended might have.

Comment: @JAY-DEV: that's nothing to do with the premise of this post. Bounties are subject to the same rules as votes: if you delete your post the rep is gone *unless the post was at least 60 days old and has a score of 3 or higher*.

Comment: "Buying or selling reputation, bounties and **other favours** is a form of voting fraud and not permitted." Please clarify what "other favours" mean.

Comment: @4386427: any other action on this site that might benefit the account but would not normally be possible without creating additional accounts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters rep handling for bounties on deleted posts is probably stricter than that of regular votes. If memory serves during mass migration from MSE to MSO I've got a bunch of bounties lost and refunded even though respective posts were well over 60 days age and 3 score (can't complain because total balance of lost/refunded was much in my favor:)

Comment: I agree 100% that this is voting fraud, it's unacceptable and it has to end. But please can we have less of this: _"As always, if you know of anyone offering such services, please flag a post (theirs or your own) for moderator attention and tell us anything you might know: who is selling, where they are advertising and if you know of anyone having used the service offered."_ Reading that leaves a pretty bitter taste. Soliciting for informers? Really? Are you comfortable with that?

Comment: @4386427: of course, mentoring has never been a problem. And if someone wants to pay for something the community can do for free if you ask nicely, then that's their choice. :-)

Comment: @Rounin: absolutely. The point is not to solicit, but to make sure that anyone wanting to alert the moderator team to something unseemly gives us the information we need. This site is community moderated, and plenty of people volunteer their time to help out the moderator team (whom are all also volunteers), so we want to make sure their time is well spent and communication is efficient.

Comment: @gnat: the MSE-MSO split and migration was rather a special case, I wouldn't take how rep was handled in that case as applicable to normal post deletion.

Comment: @Rounin to continue the venerable tradition of law enforcement comparisons in this thread: yes, and they rightfully feel so. The only cultures where "ratting out" is frowned upon are the criminal cultures. See [omertà](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omert%C3%A0) of the Italian mafia for an example. Any user that informs mods about voting (or any other) fraud does a great service for the community.

Comment: @OlegValter I think committing a criminal offence in your country and facing a life changing jail sentence would be a bit more of a deterrent than breaching the terms of service for a website and facing getting your account suspended (and then presumably just creating a new one). im sure the net effect of this post will be the opposite of what it was trying to achieve. Until I saw this post the thought would never have entered my brain that people would pay money for stack overflow internet points

Comment: @rdans This post will definitely raise awareness of the site's curator base to be on the look-out for such patterns. The consequences of being caught may not be as severe as breaking state laws, but I high doubt that a post presenting the fact that there are _consequences and that they will be found eventually_ will bring a net positive to any eventual Streisand effect.

Comment: @rdans people pay money to get fully leveled up World of Warcraft characters, essentially so they don't actually have to play the game to be able to show off :)

Comment: Re: _"The only cultures where "ratting out" is frowned upon are the criminal cultures. "_ - a sweeping statement, demonstrably untrue. In this case moderators should probably do their job without cheaply encouraging and relying on police-state-style informants. Stack Overflow is a profitable commercial company which derives profit from information freely volunteered and shared between peers. SO is not a charity and has no wish to become a charity. So we are right to treat SO like a business. Have a look at the remunerations of a couple of SO execs. Those salaries represent a lot of value.

Comment: @Rounin surely if it is demonstrably untrue you can demonstrate that? :) Also, please do not forget that the goals of the for-profit company such as SO and the goals of the community does not have to be in sync. A *byproduct* of the company's greed is still an amazing resource for developers all over the world. So if we are to keep that much, we better *never* treat the network the same way the company does. Also of note is the fact that there is business, and then there is fraud. Selling accounts/votes/posts is the latter by definition. P.s. Reporting wrongdoing to authorities has nothing...

Comment: ...to do with being a police state. Given where I live, I can definitely tell you a thing or two about what a police state is.

Comment: May I ask how you know that the buyer is complicit in the transaction?  For _theoretical_ example - what is to stop me buying this service on behalf of user _xyz_ with whom I have had a petty argument in chat, and then getting his account suspended or sanctioned?

Comment: @Martin easiest way to address this would to spare "client account" suspension and only revert their rep gains. If they didn't pay for the service this is painless

Comment: @Rounin ah, I see, I see :) It's been quite the opposite of a police state 25 years ago, though [sorry everyone, wrapping up the politics]. More on point, what I meant is that there is nothing wrong with encouraging people to report clearly illegal activity. It is only when the laws are unjust that it becomes an issue. And in the case of selling accounts I highly doubt the treatment of such "businessmen" is unjust.

Comment: @gnat You're right, but the post explicitly states "_you could end up with a profile with a suspension notice._".  I don't see how this can be enacted without proof that the account receiving the rep actually bought the service in question.

Comment: @Martin: I'm not going to disclose this, but in all cases we have solid proof that there was a client-service relationship that led to the rep increase.

Comment: @Rounin: The moderator team consists of **volunteers**. We work hard to keep the site workable for everyone, and that includes battling fraud. And because we are volunteers, we have limited time and resources, and so welcome help from the wider community gladly. What the company execs receive in salary has **nothing to do with any of this**. The company is providing a platform, but it is up to us, the community, to make the place liveable.

Comment: @rene so Stock Exchange will soon support margin reputation `:)`

Comment: @BernhardBarker oh, that's true, not saying buyers should go unscathed and agree that the most appropriate punishment is the subtraction of everything they received via the "service". Ensuring the unlawfully earned cannot be kept is usually enough of a deterrent for buyers since, well, the reason they buy these services is to boost their account (or whatever).

Comment: Replacing these worthless internet points with tokens (alike BAT on GitHub) would eliminate all motivation to sell them in such an indirect way, but would permit them to be withdrawn.

Comment: Wow... It is rare to see engineers with such a business sense... Honestly I am confused whom to be more impressed with... The one who started it or the one who caught this.... Us mere mortals didn't had even an imagination that this could be done....

Comment: @Richie please don’t transcribe the image. The goal here is to serve an illustration of the kinds of adverts we found, not for the text to be searchable and indexed. I *deliberately* made it an image, not text.

Comment: This is still showing up with double-encoding as "Don&#39;t be that account: buying and selling reputation and bounties" underneath "Featured on Meta", as [reported two days ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410831/dont-be-that-account-buying-and-selling-reputation-and-bounties?cb=1#comment860875_410831).

Comment: @AndrewMorton it comes and goes. Most of the time the apostrophe is rendered correctly.

Comment: So it does! Should I blame caching?

Comment: @AndrewMorton why not? I certainly do!

Comment: I'm kind of amused that this is being voted to close as opinion based. It's a policy announcement... what the heck.

Comment: @Gimby guess some people think that buying/selling accounts being a fraud is opinion-based :) Just as surprised as you are - all close voters are also veteran users, which is kind of amusing.

Comment: The note says "*you could end up with a profile with a suspension notice.*". That seems to be inviting black hat suspension services akin to blackhat link farming. How does SO determine if the target account holder should be the one to be suspended or if they are the victim?

Comment: @JonSG evidence.

Comment: @KevinB What evidence would say that I am the victim of a black hat smear campaign or perpetrator of a black hat vote fraud if "evidence" is voting irregularities on SO? Google tried this every thing and people quickly learned to abuse it leading to having to 'disavow' links. Put a second way, how would you prove your innocence if someone else purchased 10k rep from known shady rep farms for your SO account leading to that account being suspended?

Comment: @JonSH the same way you don't currently get banned just because someone decided to serial upvote you. If there isn't enough evidence, there isn't enough evidence. We're not talking about an automated process here.

Comment: @JonSG simplest example of evidence that springs to mind is when client account gets a posting block release triggered by fraudulent upvotes from provider account

Comment: The world is increasingly becoming a witness of greater depths at which Humanity can stoop.

Comment: "Buying or selling reputation, bounties and other favours is a form of voting fraud and not permitted." Except via Collectives™, that is.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "The company is providing a platform, but it is up to us, the community, to make the place liveable." I'm disgressing but somewhat disagreement here. The relationship between community and company is symbiotic. One cannot exist without the other. It's not separable like this and the community can and should also demand reasonable actions from the company for example. It's not only on us to make the place liveable.

Comment: @Trilarion sure, and they do provide resources to help the moderator team: the Community Managers help out in cases like these. That still doesn’t make the salaries of executives at the company relevant.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what do you think about tagging this [meta-tag:faq]? or maybe [meta-tag:faq-proposed], although at 8K views and 300+ upvotes this seems to already qualify for FAQ

Comment: 13 downvoters. Shouldn't we create a panel for these "suspects"? 