# Cheating them out of an education or it’s just hypocrisy

Tags: discussion

If you read through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75008668/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-java) ([link to picture for < 10k)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4K2f.png)), there is a new contributor who has asked a question about reversing a string in Java. He was new to the site and someone provided an answer, but then the answer got downvoted and the stated reasons for downvoting were

> We don't do other people's homework, it's cheating them out of an education.

My question is:

a) How did the guy who commented figure out it was a homework question? It could well be just the OP is doing his own self-guided venture into the Java programming language.

b) Most probably the guys who say they can't do other people's homework, do contract assignment, help sites, and get paid to do hard programming assignments for students. There are very many programmers here on SO who get paid to do other people's homework.

So why would anyone think that helping someone beat a homework assignment is cheating out of education? They could learn through the help.

Comment: "Most probably [...] get paid to do hard programmig assignments for students" - citation needed

Comment: The point is millions of programmers do academic writing as a side hustle, even SO contributors.

Comment: "*There are very many programmers here on SO who get paid to do other people's homework.*" not sure if you meant on SO, but [Don't be that account: buying and selling reputation and bounties](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410831/2821954)

Comment: 'answer got downvoted and stated the reasons for downvoting to be' - please note that (down/up) votes and comments aren't related.

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Also, do you have any kind of evidence to support your claim? Your only reply to bmm6o's comment requesting a citation was to make another unsupported assertion.

Comment: Some of the comments in the question might be gone by now, but this still feels like an overreaction to a bad question being, as expected, being badly received. If anything, we can continue inviting people to keep downvoting and moving along in these cases, rather than trying to educate the neverending masses.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum!

Comment: The comment should have been flagged either as NLN or unkind. Please do not leave comments like this.

Comment: The rest of your question is really based on the unfriendly comment, so I see no reason to delve into it.

Comment: *...Most probably...* no, most probably **not**. *...millions of programmers do academic writing as a side hustle...* I don't believe there is anywhere near that many. Do have a reference for that claim?

Comment: I'm even more surprised that the OP didn't even bother a single second to do some research on that topic. He could have written that question title into any search engine and would get several answers on different sites. Why do people think that in 2023 you still need to ask the most basic things about established technologies and why do people keep answering the same questions over and over again?

Comment: @Tom: Well, he could have [a vested interest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417632/request-to-let-banned-users-ask-one-question-every-week#comment906279_417632)...

Comment: Paid homework is a form of corruption. We find it *abscheulich*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, We? Don't over generalize, use I instead, you can't know what everyone do in the wholeness of their lives. Asserting that they are not getting paid to other people's homework is assuming beyond the threshold. In every 10 software engineers, at least 2 do it

Comment: @PeterMortensen Oh, I forgot that meta post already. Thanks for the reminder. Pretty funny to read, actually.

Comment: It is definitely abuse of the voting system, we don't vote to punish. But some people do, and you can't stop them. Only the comment is something that can be dealt with. It sucks, but life is not fair.

Comment: @Gimby How do you know why every voter voted and therefor know "It is definitely abuse"?

Comment: I have decades of experience in software engineering yet, strangely, I have never needed to reverse a string....

Comment: ..in fact..maybe I cannot do it!  There's all that annoying testing/debugging of pointers/indices meeting in the middle and 0/1/2 length strings.  It"s almost like it"s a purely academic exercise where the only point is to teach students how to learn by doing..

Comment: @FlaviusStandswithRussia *In every 10 software engineers, at least 2 do it* Again, where's your evidence for this? You keep making baseless claims.

Answer (score 27):

I mean, [academic dishonesty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_dishonesty) is a *problem*, but...

- it's not *our* problem, and
- it really *does* cheat the student out of a legitimate education or opportunity to learn.

In this case I don't think that question you linked to even comes close to coming close to the standard of a homework question.  It was just...really bad.  No code, no explanation, no *nothing*.  It's just asking us to do their work for them, which is bad even *before* we talk about anything education-related.

The commentator was out of line; the question should just have been unceremoniously closed.

Comment: Not sure I agree the the commenter was out of line (although I guess you could say that telling other people not to answer is [arguably not constructive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348633/is-a-comment-telling-someone-not-to-answer-constructive)).

Comment: the comment wasn't needed, is more hostile than it needs to be, and is also simply wrong. If an answerer feels their answer will be useful to the OP and future visitors, it's certainly correct for them to provide it regardless of the OP's education level or purpose for being here.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine: In no universe, present, AU or otherwise, would a comment on Stack Overflow saying, "We don't do other people's homework" be an acceptable comment.  If the question isn't on-topic then just *close* the question.  If it's not useful then just *downvote* the question. Why comment at all?

Comment: I'll agree that it's more hostile than necessary in its phrasing, but it was also wrong for the answerer to just do the whole assignment for the OP.

Comment: I mean, i do think it's *wrong* on some levels, but it's not *wrong* in the sense that we should do anything about it or leave comments suggesting it shouldn't have been posted. It's certainly a disservice to education on some levels, but that's not our problem to solve.

Comment: It is not wrong to answer homework question as long as it is on-topic ("how to reverse string" is perfectly valid on-topic question, does not require extra info to be one)... It is wrong so to answer duplicate question - downvoting answer that is no better than well known duplicate is fine in my book (as "not useful") .