# "Your Daily Reviews" progress bar floats left in Triage, since there's no "Filter" button

Tags: bug, review-queues, design, triage

When looking at the review queues, there are four that are available to <2k rep users:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The daily reviews has a progress bar justified to the right.

For the Triage queue, you can see the progress bar is floating to the left.

I think that the Triage queue should mimick the same format as the other queues and have the progress bar float right.

Comment: Presumably, this is because there is no "Filter" button for the Triage review queue, and thus the grid/flexbox/whatever-layout-system-they're-using-now isn't working as it was intended to. Therefore, I consider this to be a bug, not a feature request.

Comment: @CodyGray most sensible solution for this would be to [provide a filtering functionality for Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/409089/839601). :) But I bet this issue will be instead resolved by useless tweaking and patching of visuals