# 10kers the delete list exist, have fun! (it's also the undelete list)

Tags: discussion, 10k-tools, psa

I've seen a baffling statement from some trusted users:

> there is no easy way to challenge or **reviewing deletions** [...] **only people who already have the link have a chance to edit/undelete**

Well, actually there is, ready for all your deletion and undeletion needs. It's on https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete. There's also SEDE to search for deleted post with certain tags or older than 30 days.

Now you can't argue that you don't know ;)

Comment: That's not a queue and only shows a few recent ones. It's not remotely the same

Comment: I'd call it a list...

Comment: @Zoe what would you call it? This question says it's one https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278174/792066

Comment: @Braiam I'd call it a list. [This is what it looks like](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/627955613737025549/846371039414845450/unknown.png) - you really shouldn't do a PSA when you have no idea what the tool looks like...

Comment: @Zoe I know exactly what it looks like. I'm 10ker in 3 other sites. But that's besides the argument. Why it isn't a queue?

Comment: Because a queue is an ordered first in, first out series of items... a list is just a list which you can arbitrarily pick from

Comment: A queue implies reviewability and the ability to find all posts with delvotes. That isn't the case

Comment: SEDE removes the author and a ton of other data. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/332043

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1412481

Answer (score 10):

Let's get to the point...

> I've seen a baffling statement from some trusted users:
>
> > there is no easy way to challenge or **reviewing deletions**

This is **completely** true. Where do I do this? For example, if I go to the [mod tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools) I can see your [other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407874/10kers-the-delete-list-exist-have-fun-its-also-the-undelete-list) in both the recently undeleted **list**, and that it has a recent undelete vote (for those not familiar with the tool, the "(2)" means it needs 2 more to be undeleted here):
[image]
Per the statement quoted above, I want to challenge this: the other question should *not* be undeleted. I can't do this. I can't do it on the list, I can't do it on the question. I can't do it. I cannot challenge nor review this list.

There *are* chatrooms you can discuss this in, if you really want to, however, you (Braiam) do not have the 10K privilege on Stack Overflow, so would be unable to contribute on them.

Now, if you want to know *why* there isn't a review queue for delete/undelete that is a very different question but it should be asked on [Stack Exchange Meta](//meta.stackexchange.com) not here.

Comment: "I want to challenge this" how can you challenge close/reopen votes? I still don't get it? Why do you think that queues allow you to challenge stuff but the list doesn't?

Comment: Let's take the close queue as an example, @Braiam . I see a question in there, and I have **four** options: Vote to Close, Leave Open, Edit, and Skip. In that List I have 2 options: Vote to Undelete, or Skip. Where is my "Leave deleted" option?

Comment: I still don't get it! You seem to argue that close votes can be challenged, yet go back to saying in comments that  you can't. Can you reconcile both point of views? Why the close queue allows you to challenge something, yet at the same time you can't challenge a close vote?

Comment: *" yet go back to saying in comments that you can't"* Again, where is my "Leave deleted" option in the "Deleted Queue {List}"  like I have in the Close Votes Queue, @Braiam ? I *can* challenge a Close vote in the review queue, I cannot challenge a (un)delete vote in the mod tool lists.

Comment: It seems that we are entrenched on a misunderstanding about the complete tooling available to us.  if I, as you say, challenge the close vote on the queue, that doesn't prevent the post from being closed outside of it, so it's not challenge more so that it's a "I refuse to allow random users to coordinate actions on this queue". That doesn't seem such challenge to me, since a motivated user would find a way to get that question closed. I expect challenges as prevent the post from being closed. A queue seems to be weak sause for that.

Comment: Questions still enter the queue, once a vote has been made, @Braiam . If the question was Closed because of those that are active in the tag closed it, then they simply *beat* the review queue; that doesn't mean that how they always are. Again, if you want a review queue for (un)delete then ask about that as a feature request on [meta.se].

Comment: That scenario seems to ignore that even if the queue completes first, users outside of the queue still can delete it. Your "challenge" is merely kicking it out of the queue, not invalidating close votes.

Answer (score 7):

Let me just apply a different highlighting to that quote:

> **there is no easy way** to challenge or reviewing deletions [...] only people who already have the link have a chance to edit/undelete

A plain list without any metadata such as tags, author, votes, comments, ... or even just the actual data, such as question body and answers, is **not an easy way** to handle undeletions.

A custom SEDE query is **not an easy way** to handle undeletions.

---

Moderation-by-Users is a taxing and exhausting process. Undeletion is especially challenging, since by its very nature it is about nothing but low-quality and/or highly-disputed content.

There is no point in arguing that "there is no easy way". It's simply a fact.

Comment: One could argue the same about deletion, but  I see your point.

Answer (score -12):

There's a problem with this tool, and is that sadly is not a queue, there's no way to dispute the deletion or undeletion of a post. Also it's pretty limited on the dates of posts that you can see there (only 30 days). And yes, you offer an alternative to it that solves the later issue (SEDE), it doesn't address the former: there's no queue.

But I still can't see why that's an issue. The close/reopen queue were an addition after the fact since close/reopen votes were supposed to also expire afterwards. Delete and undelete ones don't have this issue. The review queues exist because there's lack of coordination for something that is time sensitive. Delete and undelete votes are immune to this.